# LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae

Tags: packages, templates, cv

If you have a TeX'ed resume, did you use a template or make your own? Are there any useful packages? What looks the most professional? How about special considerations for different areas of work (e.g. in academia)?

Comment: An article pointer and discussion at Hacker News, [Why I do my resume in LaTeX](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2238408), will interest some people here, I think.

Comment: You could look at [How to show off TeX skills with a TeX-typeset CV?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/204964/34551).

Comment: A friend of mine built a CV similar, I made some updated to work in French an I have add a cover letter. 
The source code is [here](https://github.com/davebulaval/CV_template) .

Answer (score 225):

For my current CV, I ended up using **[moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/)**. It doesn’t have many features but it is very easy to use and yields a very elegant output.

However, I also want to mention its drawbacks: customising it isn’t easy, especially since it doesn’t really use a clean, semantic markup. For example, to specify multi-column properties, you actually need to specify the items in an odd order (namely line by line instead of column wise).

Comment: Another vote for moderncv.  To my eye (after having read hundreds of CVs over the past year's hiring), it presents the information in a way that makes it easy for the reader to find what they are looking for.  This is critical to getting past the first pass.

Comment: I’m attempted to downvote my own answer. I’ve recently had to change my CV slightly and it was imperative that everything fit on one page, which, from the available space, wasn’t a problem in principle. However, moderncv simply doesn’t accomodate such wishes. I ended up rewriting large parts of it, in an extremely quick&dirty way since I didn’t have a lot of time. In hindsight, creating my own class from scratch would have cost me less time. As soon as I’ve got time I’ll rewrite my CV without any template.

Comment: `moderncv` actually has a new feature (or a related package) since yesterday: [moderntimeline](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderntimeline).

Comment: @Konrad Any chance you could elaborate on the issue? Normally, you can simply change the margin of the pages through geometry, or decrease the inter-element spacing through the optional parameter of every command.

Comment: @Xavier Changing the margins wasn’t an option, and changing the inter-element spacing proved to be a major pain in the *ss. In particular though I tried putting some of the elements in two columns next to each other and that didn’t go down well with the package.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Any chance your *CV without any template* turns into a nice successor class for the community to use? ;)

Comment: @gerrit Unfortunately I never got around to it since I haven’t touched my CV since then (I’ve changed positions in the meantime but that application required a CV in tab-delimited plain text format …).

Comment: My only issue with modern CV is that it has a tendency to create fairly lengthy resumes.  Given the same input with a different template my resume tends to be a good bit shorter.  (I tend to use the defacto [resume](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/resume/) package )

Comment: I clicked on the link and decided to check out the examples. For what it's worth, this looks terrible: http://mirror.its.dal.ca/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template-zh.pdf

Comment: The key point is that Chinese names are written family name first, and the template got it wrong. To correct it would wreck the effect of the shading (since obviously the family name needs to be darker). Moreover italics don't translate over into Chinese very nicely (the language is made of square block-shaped characters and there is no natural disposition in Chinese to write them on a slant), but the brackets around them are slanted! The effect is hilariously mis-shappen parenthesis around characters.

Comment: They also got the cultural context of the addresses wrong at the bottom of the page, addresses are written outwards in in Chinese (ie city -> district -> street -> building number), but that's a minor detail.

Comment: @chell Thanks for the information. As mentioned above, I’ve had my own problems with this template and I’m no longer using it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw your comment and was curious to check out the template due to the large number of upvotes to your answer.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph, thank you for the answer. I am using moderncv and hope to extend the width of the text slightly because I don't want a line break with a single in the next line, for example in the items of `\section{Education}`. I didn't see any option for the adjustment. Could you give some suggestion?

Comment: @Enter Apologies, I no longer use any premade CV document class, I now use my own because I was not happy with any of them. I also haven't touched my CV in years so I can't really comment.

Answer (score 142):

I made my own. In the end, it was much easier that way; you get what you want. Especially if you have situations in which you need to quickly prepare e.g. a 4-page CV, you know how to tweak your own layout to meet the requirements.

Some key tools:

- `article` class
- `geometry` package for margins
- `hyperref` to have a nice PDF (e.g., DOI hyperlinks in the list of publications, proper PDF metadata)
- `enumitem` for tweaking list layout; `titlesec` for section headings
- `cite`, `url`, `microtype`, `babel`, ...
- Keep layout and content separated; easy to do something like `\input{layout2}\input{content}` to produce yet another version with a different layout.
- `multibib` to get multiple lists of references in the CV (one for journal papers, another for conference papers, etc.):

  ```
  \newcites{jrnl}{Journal Papers}
  \newcites{conf}{Conference Papers}
  ...
  \nocitejrnl{...}
  \nociteconf{...}
  ...
  \section{Scientific Publications}
  {
      \renewcommand{\section}[2]{\subsection{#2}}
      \setbiblabelwidth{99}
      \bibliographystylejrnl{yyy}
      \bibliographyjrnl{xxx}
      \setbiblabelwidth{99}
      \bibliographystyleconf{yyy}
      \bibliographyconf{xxx}
     ...
  }
  ```

  The "nocite" lists, etc., are automatically generated from a source file by using a Python script. The lists are actually in a separate file that I `\input`.
- A tweaked version of the `unsrt` Bibtex style: I added things like DOI links, etc., by using some ugly hacks.
- JabRef + some scripts to maintain the Bibtex database.
- Rubber (with `% rubber: module pdftex`) for compiling everything. It works OK with multibib.

Comment: Could you share an example of this, and typical output, please?

Comment: +1 on the previous comment: unless your answer is an imperative: "Do it yourself!", I think it would be really nice to see (at least) an MWE... +2 on inputting layout, seems like an elegant way!

Comment: In 2020 you could check https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How_to_write_a_LaTeX_class_file_and_design_your_own_CV_(Part_1)

Answer (score 79):

[ShareLaTeX](https://www.sharelatex.com/) provides a list of [CV/Resume Templates](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume), including:

- [ModernCV Oldstyle](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-oldstyle)

  [image]
- [ModernCV Casual](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-casual)

  [image]
- [ModernCV Classic](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-classic)

  [image]
- [ModernCV Banking](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-banking)

  [image]
- [EuropeCV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/europecv)

  [image]
- [SC_CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/sc_cv)

  [image]
- [Classic Thesis Style - CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/classic-thesis-style---cv)

  [image]
- [Academic CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/academic-cv)

  [image]
- [Professional CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/professional-cv)

  [image]
- [Two-Column CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv)

  [image]
- [Fancy CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/fancy-cv)

  [image]
- ECV Curriculum Vitae ([English](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/ecv-cur%C2%ADricu%C2%ADlum-vi%C2%ADtae-english-versioin) or [German](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/ecv-cur%C2%ADricu%C2%ADlum-vi%C2%ADtae-(german)))

  [image]
- [Curve](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/curve)

  [image]
- [ESIEEcv](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/esieecv)

  [image]
- [currvita](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/cur%C2%ADrvita)

  [image]
- [Cies Breijs Resume](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/cies-breijs-resume)

  [image]
- [CV US](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/cv-us)

  [image]
- [Clean CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/clean-cv)

  [image]
- [Deedy Resume](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/deedy-resume)

  [image]
- [KJH Vita](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/kjh-vita)

  [image]
- [Extended Fancy CV (Carmine Benedetto)](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/extended-fancy-cv-(carmine-benedetto))

  [image]
- [Designer's CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/designer's-cv)

  [image]
- [Thomas Jansson CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/thomas-jansson-cv)

  [image]
- [Indian Institute of Technology Bombay Resume](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/indian-institute-of-technology-bombay-resume)

  [image]
- [Academic Researcher CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/academic-researcher-cv)

  [image]
- [Simple CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/simple-resume-cv)

  [image]
- [Awesome CV](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/awesome-cv)

  [image]

Comment: I second @Diego! Thank you @werner and +1 for the pictures!

Comment: Wow, great collection with samples! I scrolled back the half-mile to upvote.

Comment: How do you use teh overleaf ones? I copy and pasted the code into TexShop but it wont typeset

Comment: @user71207: Since they are templates, they may require style and class files, all of which are contained within the Overleaf project/template. You should download them all (the entire project) and maintain the Overleaf file structure (which could include subfolders), then you should be able to compile the main file.

Answer (score 71):

There are lots of resume examples here with source: http://rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/.

Google can show a thousand other examples, but that's a good place to start.

Comment: that's the one i use... pretty nice.

Comment: Actually, these are all extremely space-y. Anything more compact? P.S. A google search puts this page at the top...

Comment: I didn't like the samples too much. Too simple and colorless! :)

Answer (score 49):

I like [europass](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/europasscv) and everyone seems impressed when they see the results... specially for Europe applications!

Comment: The link is dead @YuppieNetworking. Can you post it somewhere else?

Comment: Updated the link for @alekhine

Comment: When you use it —and I wholeheartedly recommend it— just be sure to leave out the original "Europass" logo. If not, the Brits will have a good laugh with your Europ ass...

Answer (score 46):

I will second the Taraborelli CV templates at http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex. In the past I've used the curve and moderncv packages but, in the end, found the combination of his elegant templates + xelatex to be the simplest and most flexible solution. I wasn't constrained by particular sectioning, etc.

Personally, I use the Hoefler Text+Optima. I also like the Caslon.

Answer (score 33):

The TeX Catalogue list CV packages in a category:

- [Writing Applications for a Job / CV](http://dante.ctan.org/tex-archive/obsolete/help/Catalogue/bytopic.html#applications)

By the way: I wasn't satisfied by the results of such packages. So, I used scrartcl and tabularx to typeset my CV. This way I could match it to the design of my application letter done with scrlttr2. I used tabularx in macros, allowing easy adjustments for all parts of the CV at once. Simple and elegant, no fancy colored lines and the like.

*Copied from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1534/are-there-any-other-packages-defined-to-create-a-cv-except-the-moderncv-package) to this topic following a request.*

**EDIT:** The original link to the TeX Catalogue was dead. The TeX Catalogue might be superseded by https://ctan.org/topics/highscore, especially https://ctan.org/topic/cv for CV.

Comment: The link is not working anymore.

Comment: @Roman (and Stefan, of course), I took the liberty of updating the link for a functional one. I hope it's OK.

Comment: I don't know if this is a mirror of the link above, nonetheless here it is: http://texcatalogue.ctan.org/bytopic.html (Last modified: 10 June 2016)

Answer (score 27):

[This](http://kjhealy.github.com/kjh-vita/) strikes me as a particularly good example of a CV or *vita*. The latex code can be seen [here](https://github.com/kjhealy/kjh-vita/blob/master/kjh-vita.tex). As an example, see the [author's vita](https://kieranhealy.org/vita.pdf).

Answer (score 26):

For  typesetting bidirectional resumes in languages other than english, the `bidi` package provides `bidimoderncv2` class for typesetting resumés, which is the modified version of `moderncv` class. Two examples are presented in the `doc` folder of the package, namely `test-casualcv.tex` and `test-classiccv.tex` than you can look and learn how you can use it.

This is an example use of `bidimoderncv` with `classic` style:
[image: example use of <code>bidimoderncv</code> with <code>classic</code> style]

and this one is with `casual` style:
[image: example use of <code>bidimoderncv</code> with <code>casual</code> style]

Take note that both are taken from examples of the package and are typeset in persian, but works fine in any other languages (whether `ltr` or `rtl`).

Comment: Can you tell me how can I compile the test-classiccv.tex file? should it be with pdfLatex or XeTex?

Comment: It should be with xelatex, since it is based on `bidi`, and it only works with xelatex.

Answer (score 20):

Recently added document class, [`cv4tw`](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cv4tw/) by Geoffrey Gouez, offers a "LaTeX CV class, with extended details".

> The class offers entries for assets and social networks; customizable
>   styles are provided. The class comes with no documentation, but a
>   worked example offers some guidance.

This package is still under development but it shows great progress. Here is a sample screen shot of an example made using the class file.

[image]

Here is a direct link to the example above: [sample-jules-verne](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/cv4tw/examples/). Note this requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX to run. Also note that the example given does not compile directly because the `samplepic.jpg` file is not provided; just replace it with your own or download it [here](https://github.com/Cicatrice/cv4tw) from GitHub under examples.

Comment: It's a fantastic new solution for CV writing in Latex (+1). Unfortunately there is no reasonable documentation available.

Comment: This is really a power house of new template. As a former `moderncv` user, it feels so much more versatile.

Answer (score 16):

I can offer you a video tutorial I made recently, which covers this topic using the article class. I just got hired for a lectureship position last week, so I think it is pretty good!

- [TeX Tutorial 9: Formatting & CV Design Part 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fJ6ZmMkOn8&feature=youtu.be)
- [TeX Tutorial 9: Formatting & CV Design Part 2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZ2EYFM3duk)

Comment: The video was removed from youtube because it was too long. You should probably upload it somewhere else and update the link.

Comment: I just noticed that and fixed it. Should be ready to go by the time you see this again.

Comment: Many Thanks! :) I think the best way is to use the article class since you can do what ever you want. :)

Comment: That would be nice if you provided the source .tex file too. :)

Answer (score 13):

I also ended up making my own style, however, I added one twist: I actually store my CV in XML format and then use an XSLT transform to convert it into a `.tex` file.  While this required a lot more work upfront, the benefit is that I can use the same XML file to generate plain text, HTML, abridged, *&c.* versions without having to maintain *n* separate files.  If you end up making your own LaTeX style for your CV, I would also suggest you seriously consider investing the time to use the XML/XSLT technique.  You can see the results of this technique [here](http://www.sultanik.com/cv) (scroll to the bottom of the page to see the XML and HTML versions).  It would take me a bit of time to clean them up, but I'd be happy to share my XSLTs with people if anyone is interested.  [This is an open source project that does something similar](http://xmlresume.sourceforge.net/), however, it was started after I created my technique and I've never used it.

Comment: I looked at the XML Resume Library a while back and noticed that it seems to be dead: last "news" is dated 2004.  I also looked at [HR-XML](http://www.hr-xml.org/hr-xml/wms/hr-xml-1-org/index.php?language=2) but then I decided I was spending too much time and used curve instead. :-)

Answer (score 13):

Ted Pavlic's CV templates are minimalistic, uses the hyperref package extensively and elegant!

http://www.tedpavlic.com/post_resume_cv_latex_example.php

Answer (score 13):

[Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) lists a whole host of [CV Templates](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tagged/cv#.Vde957KrTDc), including:

- [Modern CV and Cover Letter](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/modern-cv-and-cover-letter/vbrtdnffktzz)

  [image]
- [Your new CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/your-new-cv/xqzhcmqkqrtw)

  [image]
- [A Designer CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/a-designer-cv/klstlngczkld)

  [image]
- [Deedy Resume](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/deedy-resume/sqdbztjjghvz)

  [image]
- [Single Column Deedy CV/Resume Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/single-column-deedy-cv-slash-resume-template/zwyxmkbrfgtz)

  [image]
- [Aparna-CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/aparna-cv/ckldkvjcjwxz)

  [image]
- [Plantilla CV Español](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/plantilla-cv-espanol/ttbgvmyjcpfb)

  [image]
- [Recent Grad Resume Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recent-grad-resume-template/gjxncvsftpqr)

  [image]
- [Recent Grad CV - with photo](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recent-grad-cv-with-photo/dqfncmgrjkyy)

  [image]
- [Resume Template (short CV)](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/resume-template-short-cv/rygykfjjbydc)

  [image]
- [Friggeri CV Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/friggeri-cv-template/hmnchbfmjgqh)

  [image]
- [Awesome CV Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/tvmzpvdjfqxp)

  [image]
- [Awesome CV Cover Letter](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv-cover-letter/pfzzjspkthbk)

  [image]
- [My two column CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/my-two-column-cv/qmdfhjwnzqqy)

  [image]
- [Material CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/material-cv/rnrnhvmfxyrw)

  [image]
- [Twenty Second Curriculum Vitea in LaTeX](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae-in-latex/xknxnmscghyt)

  [image]
- [Jan Küster's Modern-looking CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/jan-kusters-modern-looking-cv/xtmmqtxpkvdh)

  [image]

Answer (score 12):

I've been using a lightly tweaked version of Michael DeCorte's [res.cls](http://www.math.nyu.edu/student_resources/res.cls). No idea if it is best of breed (nor why I chose it), but if it ain't broke. . . .

Answer (score 11):

I found [CurVe](http://www.lrde.epita.fr/~didier/software/latex.php#curve) to be a nice package. Used it to get two student jobs and apparently, it worked :). The only drawback is that the default structure of the CV may need adjustments to your specific purposes.

Answer (score 10):

For my current one I just rolled my own. I use `fancyhdr` for the header and footer, and `lastpage` so that I can display  `page x/y` in the footer (so that the person reviewing it would know if they lost a page).

The entirety of the rest of the document is built from nested customized `list`s.

Comment: +1 on `fancyhdr`.

Answer (score 10):

I ended up making my own, but it took a while. Expect to have to fight LaTeX's defaults on a lot of things. That said, it's worth it. I learned a lot about LaTeX and have a good resume that I can say I wrote.

I wouldn't be surprised, but it seems like if you're going to use LaTeX for your resume, be prepared to answer truthfully whether you used a template or not, and be comfortable with the answer.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem even if you used a template, the purpose of the resume is to present the professional skills, not the low-level LaTeX skills.

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example of a nice-looking "home-made" CV: http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to use LaTeX along with BibTeX, I have a template here:

http://pointsofsail.org/wikka.php?wakka=LatexCV

It is based on Dario Taraborelli's template (http://nitens.org/taraborelli/cvtex) and uses bibtex and the bibentry package to make the publications section.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a Hacker News thread with many examples of resumes and CVs in (La)TeX:

- http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3013654

Answer (score 8):

I used `curve` to create my CV:

http://www.mhelvens.net/cv

Quite customizable by itself. But I added several hacks and convenience macros of my own:

- nicer rubric-title underlining
- separate bullet-shapes for [ongoing], [notable] and [other]
- separate year-styles for [period] and [event]
- separate year-styles for [past], [ongoing, known end-year], [ongoing, open end]
- hyperlinked cross-references
- hyperlinked e-mail and url
- for specific projects and papers: hyperlinked www or doi
- when printing, cross-refs, urls and e-mail are black; www and doi links are invisible

Someday soon I should make the code public. But for now it's a bit too chaotic to release.

Answer (score 8):

I have made my CV using predominately `BibLaTeX`. I have gone way beyond just using `BibLaTeX` for my publications, but have added a number of custom entry types (e.g., funding, service, teaching, presentation, education), modified the `biber` data model to allow for new fields and written bibliography drivers to handle the formating of these new entry types. Everything except my contact information is stored in a bib file (and technically my contact information is stored in the @preamble entry). Each version of my CV is produced by a tex file that sets a few `BibLaTeX` booleans and defines a bunch of `\defbibfiler` and `\defbibcheck`.

I find this makes it much easier for me to reorganize/reorder my CV. Previously it was easy to move my "teaching" section before my "service" section, but with `BibLaTeX` I can have my teaching in a big list or divide it into undergraduate and graduate or University A and University B. Similarly I can divide my research presentations into internal/external or into talk/poster.

Comment: Intersting approach! I would *love* to see the code for this :-)

Answer (score 6):

I have made this by adapting some parts of other curriculum, like the one called Alice. I used `tcolorbox` for the content. I also had great help from Alan Munn. Feel free to modify and use.

[image]

Save this file with this name: CV_g_Contents

Content file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=42cm,paperwidth=9cm,margin=2mm,top=5cm,bottom=2cm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}

\colorlet{DarkGray}{gray!20!black}
\colorlet{LightGray}{gray!20!white}
\pagenumbering{gobble}


%
\usepackage{fontawesome}
% Command for printing skill progress bars
\newcommand\skills[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[]
            \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {#1}{
            \begin{scope}[yshift=\i cm]
            \draw[fill=LightGray,LightGray] (0,\i) rectangle (6,\i+0.4);
            \draw[fill=white,cyan](0,\i) rectangle (\y,\i+0.4);
            \node[above right] at (0,\i+0.4) {\x };
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
}


%
\tcbset{breakable,
enhanced jigsaw, colframe=DarkGray!70!cyan, colback=white, enhanced,boxed title style={colback=black,},sharp corners,boxrule=0pt,
%left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0.2cm,
}
\begin{document}
\clearlight
\begin{tcolorbox}[top=0pt]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=9cm]{example-image}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.8cm} X}
\midrule
{\color{black!50!cyan} {\Huge \faStarO}} & {\large 17 November 1789}
 \\
\midrule
{\color{black!50!cyan} {\Huge \faEnvelopeO}} & {\large your@email.com} 
 \\ 
\midrule
{\color{black!50!cyan} {\Huge \faPhoneSquare}} & {\large +37 (XX) 123456789}
 \\ 
\midrule
\noindent{\color{black!50!cyan}{\Huge \faHome}} & {\large Your address number, street, and so on}
 \\ 
\midrule 
{\color{black!50!cyan} {\Huge\faLinkedinSquare}} & {\large linkedin/yourname}
 \\
 \midrule 
 {\color{black!50!cyan} {\Huge\faGlobe}} & {\large www.yoursite.com}
  \\ 
\midrule 
\end{tabularx}   
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Skills]
\skills{{Skill four/5.8},{Skill three/3},{Skill two/4.3},{Skill one/4}}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Languagues]
\skills{{Español/4.3},{English/4}}

Native language: Português
\end{tcolorbox}
%
%\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Tester]
%\lipsum[1-3]
%\end{tcolorbox}
%
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Profile]
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\faSuitcase \quad Experience]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.3cm} X}
        \midrule
        \rotatebox{90}{1820} & Big Europe Company \\
         & {\color{cyan}\textbf{Junior Janitor}}  \\
         & \newcount\zz
         \loop
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
         \advance\zz1
         \ifnum\zz<8
         \repeat \\
        \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.3cm} X}      
        \rotatebox{90}{1826} & \LaTeX \, Corporation \\
         & {\color{cyan}\textbf{Great Janitor}}  \\
         & \newcount\zz
          \loop
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          \advance\zz1
          \ifnum\zz<10
          \repeat \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.3cm} X}
        \midrule
        \rotatebox{90}{1841} & 4D Printer Unlimited  \\
         & {\color{cyan}\textbf{Senior Janitor}}  \\
         & 
        \lipsum[4] \\
        \midrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=\faGraduationCap \quad Education]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.3cm} X}
    \midrule
    \rotatebox{90}{1820} & Random University \\
     & {\color{cyan}\textbf{Hard Engineering}}  \\
     & \newcount\zz
     \loop
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
     \advance\zz1
     \ifnum\zz<5
     \repeat \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.3cm} X}  
    \rotatebox{90}{1826} & \LaTeX \, Corporation \\
     & {\color{cyan}\textbf{Master in Janitor}}  \\
     & \newcount\zz
      \loop
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
      \advance\zz1
      \ifnum\zz<3
      \repeat \\
    \midrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{m{0.3cm} X}   
    \rotatebox{90}{1826} & \LaTeX \, Corporation \\
         & {\color{cyan}\textbf{P.h.D in Janitor}}  \\
         & \newcount\zz
          \loop
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
          \advance\zz1
          \ifnum\zz<3
          \repeat \\
        \midrule 
\end{tabularx}
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title=Background]
\lipsum[7-8]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Then the layout page:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{ClearSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\colorlet{DarkGray}{gray!20!black}
\colorlet{LightGray}{gray!20!white}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,top=4cm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\colorlet{mygreen}{black!50!cyan}

\newcommand\Header{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[mygreen]
  (current page.north west) -- (current page.north east) --
  ([yshift=+20pt]current page.north east|-current page text area.north east) --
  ([yshift=+20pt]current page.north|-current page text area.north) --
  ([yshift=+20pt]current page.north|-current page text area.north) --
  ([yshift=+20pt]current page.north west|-current page text area.north west) -- cycle;
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{black},anchor=center] at ([yshift=-40pt]current page.north)
        {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont \clearlight \MakeUppercase{Your Name}};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=center] at ([yshift=-40pt, xshift=3.5cm]current page.north west)
            {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont \clearlight --- {[}};
    \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=center] at ([yshift=-40pt, xshift=-3.5cm]current page.north east)
                {\fontsize{50}{60}\selectfont \clearlight  {]} --- }; 
        %
  \node[font=\sffamily\bfseries\color{white},anchor=center] at ([yshift=-80pt]current page.north)
        {{\Large Mechanical Janitor}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\pagestyle{empty}
\AtBeginShipoutFirst{\Header}
\begin{document}
%\begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black!40!cyan]\centering {\Huge Name} \\ \bigskip {\LARGE Mechanical Engineer}
%\end{tcolorbox}
\includepdf[,pages=-,nup=3x1,columnstrict=true,]{CV_g_Contents}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I adapted the resume class found in http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~csuros/latex.html.

Answer (score 5):

[LaTeX Templates](http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae) showcases several templates, ranging from conservative to fancy.

I ended up using [Classicthesis-Styled CV](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/classicthesis-styled-cv). It caught my eye as most esthetically pleasing. And even with my poor LaTeX skills was very easy to adapt to my needs.

Answer (score 4):

I maintain a Latex template targetted for Engineers on Github, you can find it at https://github.com/sb2nov/resume

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As I haven't seen it here yet, I would like to mention `limecv` which is shipped with TeX Live (development on GitHub: https://github.com/opieters/limecv). Apart from your CV you can create a cover letter in a similar design with that package.

The following pictures are taken from the documentation.

[image: cv1]

[image: cv2]

Answer (score 3):

For a professional looking CV there is Plasmati CV, good for banking, consultancy careers. ModernCV is colored works for serious and less serious careers (communication management etc... and Friggeri CV is the template for designers etc... ModernCV is used at CVsintellect and the 3 are used in [seeveeze](http://www.seeveeze.com)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

An other quite recent style is available here: http://mrzool.cc/tex-boilerplates/ 
[image: An example]

Answer (score 1):

I prepare 2 versions of my CV; a resume; lists of publications and references; statements of teaching philosophy and research interests all on the basis of [currvita](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/currvita/). Well, with a considerable amount of hand-hacking. For added geekiness, the list of publications is primarily a specialized bibtex output format (which works nicely with getting a bibtex formatted list of my publications from [spires](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/spires/find/hep/www?rawcmd=FIND+AU+D+MCKEE+AND+NOT+AU+B.+D.+MCKEE&FORMAT=wwwcitesummary&SEQUENCE=citecount)).

Answer (score 1):

I have used the `res.cls` as explained e.g. [here](https://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/). It is one of the oldest if not the oldest template for cv's with Latex. It's been fine up to recently but I would advise *against* using it. It is not updated anymore and so I have had problems using it with newer versions of Yosemite (actually I have the same problem described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269982/unable-to-install-res-cls-matex-2015-yosemite-texshop)).