# Class for Curriculum Vitae

Tags: document-classes, templates, resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Which class do you recommend to write a CV? The answer will probably be different depending on the CV being used in the academia or in an external context (the former will probably be more "serious", and certainly it will not include a photo).

Comment: @Andrea: I'm voting to merge this question with the one about resumes (I notice that Caramdir has added the words "curriculum vitae" to that question to make it easier to find in future).  If you think that the answers there aren't what you're looking for, try editing this question to make it clear why you want something different.  (PS being from the UK I sympathise with the language issue: "resume" just doesn't register with me - particularly without the accent on the final "e"!)

Comment: The resumé/CV distinction is not just a dialect issue.  In the US at least, a resumé and a CV are quite different documents.  Try googling "difference between resume and cv".  Nevertheless, they are similar enough in format that I think merging the questions makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [moderncv](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) so far -- it gets the job done and has some pretty neat templates to get started.

Answer (score 3):

Minimalia has a nice LaTeX [tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20131029090732/http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/5) for CV. Pretty nice cover letter also.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `currvita`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[openbib]{currvita}
\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{CV}                                                          
\begin{cvlist}{Personal Data}
\item Name
\item Address
\end{cvlist}

\begin{cvlist}{Occupation}
\item[1999--2003] CEO of FooBar Inc.
\end{cvlist}
\cvplace{Teh Internetz}
\date{\today{}}
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```