# Are there any other packages defined to create a CV except the "moderncv" package?

Tags: packages, cv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

I'm going to make a CV of my own and I wonder wether there are some other packages focused on CV making except the `moderncv` package?

Comment: A previous question already has [many suggestions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are. Have a look at that category in the TeX Catalogue:

- [Writing Applications for a Job / CV](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#applications)

By the way: I wasn't satisfied by the results of such packages. So, I used scrartcl and tabularx to typeset my CV. This way I could match it to the design of my application letter done with scrlttr2. I used tabularx in macros, allowing easy adjustments for all parts of the CV at once. Simple and elegant, no fancy colored lines and the like.

Comment: Do you mind adding your answer to the [other](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume) question?

Comment: Ok, I've added it to that community wiki topic.