# Including an itemized list within a tabular column using the paralist package

Tags: spacing, packages, lists, itemize

The paralist package offers the option of typesetting an itemized list with a `\topsep` length of zero, and this is especially useful in a tabular setting. However, the following minimal example does not seem to remove the space at the top of the second column as would be expected when compiled with pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
\setlength{\pltopsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\plpartopsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{20mm} p{50mm}}
  Itemize: & {%
  \begin{compactitem}
    \item First item
  \end{compactitem}}\\
  Enumerate: & {% 
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item First item
  \end{enumerate}}\\
  Description: & {%
  \begin{description}
    \item[Descriptor] First item
  \end{description}}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document
```

Can someone explain how I might get the first line of the second column to line up with the first line of the first column, please?

I can workaround with a negative `\vspace` before the respective list environments but I want a more elegant solution which I think paralist is supposed to provide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Within a minipage this undesired top space would not be inserted. So, similar to the solution in [Preventing itemize environment to insert initial vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space), you could insert `\@minipagetrue` into the respective cells:

```
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother
\begin{tabular}{p{20mm}>{\compress}p{50mm}}
...
```

Your example code is fixed by this, the lines line up:

[image: list example]

Alternatively, you could define a column type for that:

```
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: I was just going to suggest `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\minipage{#1}\arraybackslash}l<{\endminipage\null}}`, but this is nicer! However you could post this as `\newcolumntype` as well. Should be easier to handle this is required more then once.

Comment: @Martin: Great idea! I added such a type declaration.

Comment: If `hyperref` is loaded for one or other reason it leaves a space before `enumerate`. Therefor use `\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue\NoHyper}`.  See the post `How to include enumerate in tabular?` http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/how-to-include-enumerate-in-tabular