# How to produce this table in latex with inconsistent lists/items?

Tags: tables, macros, itemize, tabularx, enumitem

I want to produce the first two rows of this 5-column table in LaTeX:

[image]

As you can see it is a special type of tables where we see:

- itemized lists inside but inconsistently, ie. column 4 all rows have itemizes lists inside, columns 2,3, and 5 do have itemized lists in some but not all rows, column 1 has no itemized lists at all.
- the nice alignment of the table
- the candy-eye appearance like that what `booktabs`package  was created for
- it is a compact table that contains no unpleasant spaces
- the lists have square bullets

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{empty}           % hide page number
  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}% Correct skip for caption on top
    \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
    \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
      \begin{tabular}{lp{2in}p{2in}p{2in}p{2in}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{BSL} & \textbf{Agents} & \textbf{Practices} & \textbf{Primary barriers} & \textbf{Secondary barriers} \\
        \midrule
        1 & Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults & standard microbiological practices & no primary barriers required, PPE & bench and sink required \\
        2 & - Agents associated with human diseases  - Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury, ingestion, mucous membrane exposure & BSL-1 practice plus: - limited access - Biohazard warning signs - ``Sharps'' precautions - Biosafety manual defining any needed waste decontamination or medical surveillance polices & Primary barriers: - BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of infectious materials - PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection, as needed & BSL-1 plus: - Autoclave available\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}%
  \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

The nearest answer I found was [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10885/26295), but unfortunately this answer assumes that all rows have itemized list and not some of them, so please for your kind attention to this point before labeling this post as duplicate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer would be to put the list inside a minipage or parbox, but that is not really fun.  Here is another solution with `enumitem` using the `before` and `after` keys and the command `\tablistcommand`: Use `tabitemize` when you have a cell with a list only, and clear out the `before` key with text preceding the list.  The lines are correctly aligned.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,enumitem,ragged2e}

\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{%
  leftmargin = *               ,
  label      = \textbullet     ,
  nosep                        ,
  before     = \tablistcommand ,
  after      = \tablistcommand
}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
  \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2in}}@{}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{BSL} & \textbf{Agents} & \textbf{Practices}
    & \textbf{Primary barriers} & \textbf{Secondary barriers} \\
    \midrule
    1 & Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults
      & standard microbiological practices
      & \begin{tabitemize}
        \item no primary barriers required,
        \item  PPE
        \end{tabitemize}
      & bench and sink required \tabularnewline
    2 & \begin{tabitemize}
        \item Agents associated with human diseases
        \item Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury,
          ingestion, mucous membrane exposure
        \end{tabitemize}
      & BSL-1 practice plus:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item limited access
        \item Biohazard warning signs
        \item ``Sharps'' precautions
        \item Biosafety manual defining any needed waste
          decontamination or medical surveillance polices
        \end{tabitemize}
      & Primary barriers:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all
          manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of
          infectious materials
        \item PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection,
          as needed
        \end{tabitemize}
      & BSL-1 plus:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item Autoclave available
        \end{tabitemize}\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

---

**EDIT**

It really depends on your use case, but I would probably make a table like this in a document.  If you have a very long table, it would make more sense to rotate it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{%
  booktabs,tabularx,enumitem,ragged2e,%
  caption,lipsum,showframe,geometry}

\captionsetup[table]{%
  format        = plain        ,
  font          = footnotesize ,
  labelfont     = bf           , 
  justification = centerlast   , 
  labelsep      = period       ,
  position      = top          ,
  aboveskip     = 5pt          ,
  belowskip     = 0pt
}

\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{%
  \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}%
}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{%
  leftmargin = *               ,
  label      = \textbullet     ,
  nosep                        ,
  before     = \tablistcommand ,
  after      = \tablistcommand
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
  \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}X}@{}}
    \toprule
    \scriptsize BSL & \scriptsize Agents & \scriptsize Practices
    & \scriptsize Primary barriers & \scriptsize Secondary barriers \\
    \midrule
    1 & Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults
      & standard microbiological practices
      & \begin{tabitemize}
        \item no primary barriers required,
        \item  PPE
        \end{tabitemize}
      & bench and sink required \tabularnewline\addlinespace
    2 & \begin{tabitemize}
        \item Agents associated with human diseases
        \item Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury,
          ingestion, mucous membrane exposure
        \end{tabitemize}
      & BSL-1 practice plus:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item limited access
        \item Biohazard warning signs
        \item ``Sharps'' precautions
        \item Biosafety manual defining any needed waste
          decontamination or medical surveillance polices
        \end{tabitemize}
      & Primary barriers:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all
          manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of
          infectious materials
        \item PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection,
          as needed
        \end{tabitemize}
      & BSL-1 plus:
        \begin{tabitemize}[before=]
        \item Autoclave available
        \end{tabitemize}\tabularnewline
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: With your answer you convinced me, that the `enumitem` is superior to (old) `paralist` and that it is time to use it in future. Te use of `before` and `after` in list settings is what I looking for a long time. Bravo! (+1).

Comment: +1 for using `enumitem`, could you please help with these two things: I couldn't change the shape of the bullet when I changed the line to `label = $\sqbullet$`, why? and second, could you please explain the code of `\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}p{2in}}@{}}`, I mean what is the intuition behind it? how to understand its usage? could we let be defined instead of being hard coded to `2in`, I mean to let latex automatically determine the suitable width spanning the whole `\textwidth`.

Comment: for the squared bullet I used `label= ding{110}` from the `pifont` package and it worked fine.

Comment: I tried `tabularx` by changing: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c*{4}{>{\RaggedRight}X}}` and `\end{tabularx}`. Now the table becomes narrower, which begs the question whether `tabularx` is of any help in this case.

Comment: what's the function of `@{}` at the beginning and end of the `tabular` argument?

Comment: @doctorate - Reg. `label`, I don't know where `$\sqbullet$` comes from?  Is there a package defining it?  But you solved it already.  Reg. `tabularx`, it really depends on your use case.  I took `p{2in}` because it was in code.  For this case, I would recommend `tabularx`.  I've edited my answer.  Reg. `@{}`, it kills the horizontal space at the beginning and end of the table.  Take a closer look at the position of **B**SL, it is flushed with the table.

Comment: @Zarko - You're welcome.  Indeed, `enumitem` is a good thing, you it `;-)`

Comment: for sake of completeness: square bullets could be achieved by using the `pifont` package and then `label = \tiny{\ding{110}}`, I also found that the parenths around 4 are needless so it could be writted: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l*4{>{\RaggedRight}X}@{}}`

Comment: even better, I found that `tabularx` can make the whole first column bold like this: `\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}l*4{>{\RaggedRight}X}@{}}`

Comment: I just noticed you didn't include the `[after=]` argument after `tabitemize` in row 2 column 2 where it should be as I guess, or is it so by default?

Comment: @doctorate - You need to clear out the keys with `[before=]` and `[after=]` only when you have some text before and/or after an itemized list.

Answer (score 10):

Here is an [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) version:

[image]

I have defined a `tableitems` variant of the `itemize` environment and used it inside your table. Note the ungainly hack using `\vspace` for those lists that do not have a header. Without this there is an empty line about the list.

**Code**

```
    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \newlist{tableitems}{itemize}{1}
    \usepackage{mathabx}% for \sqbullet
    \setlist[tableitems]{nosep,
                         topsep=0pt,
                         partopsep=0pt,
                         leftmargin=1em,
                         label=$\sqbullet$
    }
    \begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
      \thispagestyle{empty}           % hide page number
      \begin{table}
        \centering
        \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{\abovecaptionskip}% Correct skip for caption on top
        \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
        \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
          \begin{tabular}{lp{2in}p{2in}p{2in}p{2in}}
            \toprule
            \textbf{BSL} & \textbf{Agents} & \textbf{Practices} & \textbf{Primary barriers} & \textbf{Secondary barriers} \\
            \midrule
            1 & Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults
              & standard microbiological practices
              &\vspace{-1em}
              \begin{tableitems}
                 \item No primary barriers required
                 \item PPE
              \end{tableitems}
              & bench and sink required
            \\\midrule
            2 & \vspace{-1ex}
            \begin{tableitems}
             \item  Agents associated with human diseases
             \item Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury,
                    ingestion, mucous membrane exposure
            \end{tableitems}
            & BSL-1 practice plus:
            \begin{tableitems}
               \item limited access
               \item Biohazard warning signs
               \item ``Sharps'' precautions
               \item Biosafety manual defining any needed waste
               decontamination or medical surveillance polices
            \end{tableitems}
             & Primary barriers:
            \begin{tableitems}
               \item BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all
                   manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of
                   infectious materials
               \item PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection, as needed
            \end{tableitems}
             & BSL-1 plus:
            \begin{tableitems}
               \item Autoclave available
            \end{tableitems}
            \\
            \bottomrule
          \end{tabular}%
      \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are two more questions: how to center the table across the page? how to modify your code to let `tabularx` determine the width of the five columns automatically given that column 1 should be a narrow one compared to the remaining columns 2-5 which should all share the same length but all summing up to the total `\textwidth` length?

Comment: +1 for using `enumitem`

Answer (score 7):

Is not perfect but see, if it is useful:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\newcommand{\textblacksquare}{\rule[.2ex]{0.8ex}{0.8ex}}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage[margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
    \usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}           % hide page number
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \small\sffamily
    \caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
    \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textheight}{c*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
\thead{BSL} 
    &   \thead{Agents} 
        &   \thead{Practices} 
            &   \thead{Primary barriers} 
                &   \thead{Secondary barriers}  \\
    \midrule
1   &   Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults 
        &   standard microbiological practices
            &   \vspace{-2ex}
                    \begin{compactitem}[\textblacksquare]
                \item   No primary barriers required,
                \item   PPE
                    \end{compactitem}
                &   Laboratora bench and sink required \\
    \midrule
2   &   \vspace{-2ex}
            \begin{compactitem}[\textblacksquare]
        \item Agents associated with human diseases
        \item Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury, ingestion, mucous membrane exposure
            \end{compactitem}
        &   BSL-1 practice plus:
                \begin{compactitem}[\textblacksquare]
            \item   limited access
            \item   Biohazard warning signs
            \item   ``Sharps'' precautions
            \item   Biosafety manual defining any needed waste decontamination or medical surveillance polices
                \end{compactitem}
            &   Primary barriers:
                    \begin{compactitem}[\textblacksquare]
                \item   BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of infectious materials
                \item   PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection, as needed
                    \end{compactitem}
                &   BSL-1 plus:
                        \begin{compactitem}[\textblacksquare]
                    \item Autoclave available
                        \end{compactitem}   \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Instead of `landscape` I have used `sidewaystable` from package `rotating` and for lists inside table `compactitem` from package `paralist`. Similarly result you can obtain with `enumitem` package (with which I'm less familiar). For table I rather use `tabularx` package where for formating I use `\RaggedRight` from `ragged2e` package.

[image]

**Addendum:**
It seems that the combination of all three answers will give the best solution :-). So I combine the following

- `$\sqbullet$` from package `mathabx` package as proposed Andrew in his answer
- the way how Arash Esbati uses package `enumitem` in his answer
- `tabularx`, `sidewaystable` and `RaggedRight` aligning of text, `makecell` for columns heading as I propose in my answer.

With this the "common" code becomes:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
%    
\usepackage{mathabx}% for \sqbullet
\usepackage{enumitem}% for nice list
\newcommand{\tablistcommand}{% <-- for eliminating vertical space
                             %     before and after itemize
            \leavevmode\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}
                            }
\newlist{tableitems}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tableitems]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                     topsep     = 0pt               ,
                     partopsep  = 0pt               ,
                     leftmargin = *                 ,
                     label      = $\sqbullet$       ,
                     before     = \tablistcommand   ,
                     after      = \tablistcommand
                     }

    \begin{document}
      \thispagestyle{empty}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{sidewaystable}[h]%table
    \centering
    \small\sffamily
\caption{Wide Itemized Mixed Table}
    \label{tab:wide-item-tbl}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c*{4}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
\thead{BSL}
    &   \thead{Agents}
        &   \thead{Practices}
            &   \thead{Primary barriers}
                &   \thead{Secondary barriers}  \\
    \midrule
1   &   Not known to consistently cause diseases in healthy adults
        &   standard microbiological practices
            &   \begin{tableitems}
                \item   No primary barriers required,
                \item   PPE
                \end{tableitems}
                &   Laboratory bench and sink required \\
    \midrule
2   &   \begin{tableitems}
        \item Agents associated with human diseases
        \item Routes of transmission include per-cutaneous injury, ingestion, mucous membrane exposure
        \end{tableitems}
        &   BSL-1 practice plus:
            \begin{tableitems}[before=]% <-- nullifying before skip
            \item   limited access
            \item   Biohazard warning signs
            \item   ``Sharps'' precautions
            \item   Biosafety manual defining any needed waste decontamination or medical surveillance polices
            \end{tableitems}
            &   Primary barriers:
                \begin{tableitems}[before=]% <-- nullifying before skip
                \item   BSCs or other physical containment devices used for all manipulations of agents that cause splashes or aerosols of infectious materials
                \item   PPE: Laboratory coats, gloves, face and eye protection, as needed
                \end{tableitems}
                &   BSL-1 plus:
                    \begin{tableitems}[before=]% <-- nullifying before skip
                    \item Autoclave available
                    \end{tableitems}   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}%table
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
    \end{document}
```

With this the table looks as can be seen below:

[image]

Comment: thanks, what's the function of the `makecell` package?

Comment: +1, for letting `tabularx` determine the widths of the columns across the text width.

Comment: From `makecell` is used macro `thead`, which centering column heads and enable if necessary, to set multi line heads. From picture in your question I concluded that this will be the case but on the end this wasn't happen.

Comment: your first solution has the advantage of avoiding the `enumitem` package in case of using the beamer class because of the famous conflict between the two.

Comment: Yes, beamer heavily redefine lists, so there easy come to problems with compatibility. In most  cases `paralist` serve very satisfactory but it is less flexible as enumitem. Now  I try to define new list for usef in tables, which will have the same features as used enumitem answers here.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this table in beamer class when I used your solution with `paralist`. I don't know why. Anyway, this alone deserves another question.