# Control line space between an itemize list and next line

Tags: lists, itemize, line-spacing

I am unable to control the line spacing between the last line of itemize and the next line as shown in the figure. Can someone suggest a solution to fix this please? I also would like to know if I can get more compact list.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}


\begin{document}

    \scriptsize
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{longtable}[t]{|p{1.0cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
            \hline
            \bf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} \\\hline\hline 
            \texttt{A} & Department 
            \begin{itemize} \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
                \item \texttt{A} - Apple
                \item \texttt{B} - Boy
                \item \texttt{C} - Cat
                \item \texttt{D} - Dog
            \end{itemize}\\
            \texttt{E} &  Elephant \\   
            \texttt{F} &  Fan \\   
            \hline
        \end{longtable}
    \end{minipage}%

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292053/how-to-produce-this-table-in-latex-with-inconsistent-lists-items), maybe that helps.  BTW, why do you put `longtable` inside a `minipage`?

Comment: I'm genuinely a little confused about how you got that output when you have `\[` and `\]` instead of `[` and `]`, e.g. `\documentclass\[10pt,a4paper,oneside\]{article}`. I mean, I'm assuming you must have generated your output with a totally different file, but if so, what happened between creating that file and writing this question :S :S Also `\end{document}` shouldn't have a `]` after it

Comment: There were characters that got I added when I was dragging the image. Had to redo it but I missed some of these weird symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two variations  on the layout. I reduced the indent of the list and the vertical spacing w.r.t. the surrounding text.

Note an optional argument to a command or an environment, has be delimited by a pair of brackets (`[option]`), *not* between a pair of bracket commands (`\[option\]`). Also font commands such as `\bf` have been deprecated for more than 20 years. Use the `\textbf{…}` command instead or the `\bfseries` switch.

Last, not least, as @Zarko pointed, a long table is made to break across pages, and a minipage cannot. You can use the `multicols` environment instead.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=0.9in, vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
    \begin{longtable}[t]{|p{1.0cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} \\\hline\hline
        \texttt{A} & Department
            \begin{itemize}[wide = 0.5em, nosep, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
                \item \texttt{A} - Apple
                \item \texttt{B} - Boy
                \item \texttt{C} - Cat
                \item \texttt{D} - Dog
            \end{itemize}\\
        \texttt{E} & Elephant \\
        \texttt{F} & Fan \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
    \begin{longtable}[t]{|c|p{5.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} \\\hline\hline
        \texttt{A} & Department
            \begin{itemize}[wide = 0.5em, nosep, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
                \item \texttt{A} - Apple
                \item \texttt{B} - Boy
                \item \texttt{C} - Cat
                \item \texttt{D} - Dog
            \end{itemize}\\
        \texttt{E} & Elephant \\
        \texttt{F} & Fan \\
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The table environment `longatble` suppose to be over many pages .. so put it in `minipage` hasn't sense.

Comment: @zarko, I am new a newbie in the land of latex and trying to reuse some working parts to get job done within deadline. No philosophical reason, only desperation!

Comment: @Zarko: Perfectly right. I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you load the `enumitem` package, then you can set options for lists (single or multiple of them), including the command you need which is `after=`. For example, if you write `after=\vspace{\baselineskip}`, that's what will happen after the list.

If you want a more compact list, you can also use negative values, like `itemsep=-1mm`. In any case, check how I used these commands, because the way you used is not the standard one. To align the `longtable` to the left, add the optional argument `[l]`.

Also, make sure you check your code, you have a lot of `\[\]` where they shouldn't be, maybe a result of search and replace.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=0.9in,right=0.9in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\scriptsize
%\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{longtable}[l]{|p{1.0cm}|p{5.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \bf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} \\\hline\hline 
        \texttt{A} & Department 
            \begin{itemize}[itemsep=0pt, after=\vspace{-1ex}]
                \item \texttt{A} - Apple
                \item \texttt{B} - Boy
                \item \texttt{C} - Cat
                \item \texttt{D} - Dog
            \end{itemize}\\
        \texttt{E} &  Elephant \\   
        \texttt{F} &  Fan \\   
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
%\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: In answer you also should emphasize, that OP wrongly use options of packages and environments. Instead in `[... ]` he/she put them in math environment `\[...\]` ... Given MWE is not possible to compile.

Comment: @Zarko Ah yes, I did notice that.

Comment: The weird characters got inserted while I was trying to upload picture. It was a working example. Sorry about that. :(

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what is requestes behind of this table design, however, I will design as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,oneside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=0.9in, vmargin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|>{\ttfamily}c|>{\ttfamily}X|}
        \hline
\textbf{\textsf{Head 1}} & \textbf{\textsf{Head 2}} \\\hline\hline
        A & Department
            \begin{itemize}[wide = 0.5em, nosep, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}]
                \item A - Apple
                \item B - Boy
                \item C - Cat
                \item D - Dog
            \end{itemize}\\
        E & Elephant \\
        F & Fan \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

i.e. without `minipages`, with use of `tabularx`, which span table to desired width and define font family in column options. This make code more concise and less prone for errors. Above MWE gives:

[image]

**Addendum:**
If you for columns head use `thead` macro from `makecell` package, you can obtain:

[image]

The needed changes of above MWE are:

```
\usepackage{makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{|>{\ttfamily}c|>{\ttfamily}X|}
        \hline
\thead{Head 1} & \thead{Head 2} \\\hline\hline
... <further is the same as in above MWE > ...
```

Comment: Maybe a `twocolumns{2}` environment, if there must be text next to the table?

Comment: Maybe. Who knows? This is not evident from question.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zarko. Will try to use the approach. Initially I did not use longtables at all, my problem was alignment and auto-resizing of table to width and auto-folding of text to table size, which was not working for various combinations that I was  trying from net. And in many cases, even minipages were not starting at left, for reasons I could not comprehend at all. If only I could have found a side-by-side tables that resize nicely with folding text to proper width!