# Table with custom text inside each cell

Tags: tables, itemize

How can i create a table so that i can put bulleted texts in each cell with variable bullet points or even no bullet points and a single word like this:

[image]

A table like this does not work for me or maybe i don't know how to make it work for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \begin{tabular}{lllll}
     &  &  &  &  \\
     &  &  &  &  \\
     &  &  &  &  \\
     &  &  &  & 
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [how-to-produce-this-table-in-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292053/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                  topsep     = 0pt                       ,
                  partopsep  = 0pt                       ,
                  leftmargin = *                         ,
                  label      = \textbullet               ,
                  before     = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip},
                  after      = \vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}
                     }
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\centering
\sffamily\large
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{white}

    \begin{tabular}{|l| p{32mm} | p{22mm} |}%
    \rowcolor{gray!40}\hline
name    &   job     &   title           \\
    \rowcolor{gray!40}\hline
alan    &   \begin{tabitem}
            \item Eat
            \item Sleep
            \item Pray
            \end{tabitem}
                &   \begin{tabitem}
                    \item Good
                    \item Ugly
                    \item Bad
                    \end{tabitem}       \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note: list works only cells with behavior as `parbox` or `minipages`. Such a cells are in columns with type `p{...}` or `X` if you use `tabularx`, etc.

[image]