# Spacing issues with itemize in a table

Tags: tables, lists, itemize

I've been trying to use lists of items in a table. This was easy to do but I could not find a way to align them in the same way as plain text in a table. Let me give an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    Blah blah & 
    \begin{compactitem}
        \item First
        \item Second
    \end{compactitem} \\    
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Instead of just itemize I used `paralist` so the list gets more compact, however there is still a lot of space added before and after the list. The result looks pretty awful, I would like to have the same spacing around "Blah Blah" as I have around the items in the right cell.

[image]

I've also found some tricks to reduce the space to the upper or lower `\hline` of the cell, but none of these could match the alignment with just plain text.

Comment: Here's a solution which also provides an explanation for using `\@minipagetrue`: [Preventing itemize environment to insert initial vertical space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space). Also, this question is about the very same problem: [Including an itemized list within a tabular column using the paralist package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10494/including-an-itemized-list-within-a-tabular-column-using-the-paralist-package).

Answer (score 23):

Herbert is right on with `\@minipagetrue` removing the space at the top, but the cleanest way I've found to remove the space at both the bottom and the top is with an actual `minipage` environment.

I'm going to use [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) with `nosep` instead of instead of `paralist` and its `compactitem` because I want to use `enumitem`'s `after` option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    Blah blah &
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,after=\strut]
        \item First
        \item Second
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Note that I've experienced cases where the `after=\strut` actually adds unnecessary space below the list.  If you run into that, try just taking the strut out entirely and see if it lays out OK.

Further notes:

- Can't/don't want to specify the maximum width on that `minipage`?  Try [`varwidth`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) instead, which will shrink the box horizontally if possible:

  ```
  % Preamble:
  \usepackage{varwidth}
  % ...then, instead of minipage, use varwidth...
  \begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
  \begin{itemize}[nosep,after=\strut]
      \item First
      \item Second
  \end{itemize}
  \end{varwidth} \
  ```
- You can use `enumitem`'s `\newlist` if you don't want to type that `\begin{itemize}[nosep,after=\strut]` over and over.  For example:

  ```
  % Preamble:
  \newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
  \setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,nosep,after=\strut}
  % ...then, in your table cell...
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
  \begin{tabitemize}
      \item First
      \item Second
  \end{tabitemize}
  \end{minipage} \
  ```
- If you intend to do this a lot in a column of a table, [this answer shows how to create a compact list column type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46723/1680).  (Donald Arseneau's solution there was key to me figuring out to do `\strut`.)
- In case you're interested, [the comments in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6454/1680) explain why `minipage` gets rid of the space at the top.

Comment: Note: I had problems with `nosep`. Said it wasn't defined. I use `noitemsep`. Also I had to insert `\vspace{-2mm}` after the `minipage`-definition, since `hyperref` stupidly adds some space there. Also, it took me almost a whole day to find this solution. Exactly what I was searching, I can't believe this is not highly uprated. You, sir, deserve a medal.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paralist,array}
\makeatletter\let\MPtrue\@minipagetrue\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    Blah blah & \MPtrue
    \begin{compactitem}
        \item First
        \item Second
    \end{compactitem} \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't need array for that, right? Also I do not understand what's the deal with minipage? Thx for the answer!

Comment: @Nils: yes, I had before `>{\MPtrue}p{10cm}` and then forgot to delete array.

Comment: So the idea is basically to add \MPtrue to every cell which has items in it? I get very strange results with this, sometimes it appears not to work at all..

Comment: @Nils: give an example where it does not work!

Comment: Can't really reproduce it.. it seems to work for simple examples.. but it only removes the space before compactitem.. it's just another hack and not a real solution :(

Comment: @Nils: it works always ...

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `enumitem` package. Using it you can access various useful settings as key-value pairs:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
    \hline
    Blah blah & \begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm]\item First \item Second \end{itemize} \\    
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

If that is not enough, you can manually kill space with `\vspace*{-1.5mm}`. Asterix ensures the space is added (in this case, because the number is negative, removed).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{2cm}|p{10cm}|}
\hline
Blah blah & \vspace*{-0.2cm}\begin{itemize}[topsep=-0.5cm,leftmargin=0.3cm]\item a \item b \end{itemize}\\    
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Both the answer and the result seem very ugly to me.

[image: List in a table without spacing]