# Extra line of vertical separator using itemize in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, columns, tabularx

I'm creating a resume based off of the example tutorial [HERE](http://stefano.italians.nl/archives/50). It's fairly simple, actually -- just a two columned table with dates on the left and job on the right. I prefer bullets vs. a paragraph for the explanations, and also liked the look of a vertical separator, so I tried to go with something like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{0.97\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\scshape}p{2.75cm}|X}

\small{09/2008 -- Present} & \textbf{Title} \\
& Company Name Here $\cdot$ City, State
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=4pt,parsep=0pt,topsep=3pt]
    \item Some stuff that I did to fill in a bullet.
    \item Some more stuff that I did just to make sure I have one example of a two
      line bullet here for variety's sake.
\end{itemize} \\
\end{tabularx}
```

I'm using the `enumitem` package to play with `itemize` spacing, and this is the `tabularx` package. as recommended in the linked blog post.

I get an extra line of vertical separator in the table when I do this, like so (see how the separator carries down about a line after the text stops?):

I also tried switching to regular 'ol `tabular` but got the same results:

```
\begin{tabular}{r|p{13.7cm}}

\small{09/2008 -- Present} & \textbf{Title} \\
& Company Name Here $\cdot$ City, State
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=4pt,parsep=0pt,topsep=3pt]
    \item Some stuff that I did to fill in a bullet.
    \item Some more stuff that I did just to make sure I have one example of a two
      line bullet here for variety's sake.
\end{itemize} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Lastly, on a fluke, I had an extra end brace inserted in tabular and found a magic fix! Switching that `\end{tabular}` to `\end{tabular}}` gave some errors.

See the difference? I tried the same with `tabularx` (since it makes an easier time for specifying widths and such), but it doesn't even render the table with them present.

Any thoughts as to what's going on and how I can legitimately get rid of that extra line without "cheating"? In my skimming, I ran across people trying to get rid of *top* whitespace in tables (like [HERE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space)), but using the `\compress` trick didn't fix my problem either.

Comment: Your images were uploaded using a 'normal' Imgur account. Could you re-upload using the 'include graphic' button in the editor: this uses a paid-for account and so the images will not expire.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a real fix, but if you say, as the final lines of the `itemize`,

```
line bullet here for variety's sake.\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\end{itemize} \\
```

you get rid of that vertical space.

Comment: Huh. That does, indeed, work. Any idea why 1) itemize is inserting a "ghost line" after the end of the list or 2) why this works to fix it? Is it just inserting negative space afterward?

Comment: I don't know precisely; apparently TeX goes into typesetting a new empty paragraph after the list. So I defeat it by inserting a negative space that compensates it.

Comment: Interestingly, I got an overfull hbox with your code until I added `\noindent` in front of the table.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the `itemize` in a `minipage` to get rid of the space afterwards, I think.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{0.97\linewidth}{>{\raggedleft\scshape}p{2.75cm}|X}

\small{09/2008 -- Present} & \textbf{Title} \\
&
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
Company Name Here $\cdot$ City, State
\begin{itemize}[itemsep=4pt,parsep=0pt,topsep=3pt]
    \item Some stuff that I did to fill in a bullet.
    \item Some more stuff that I did just to make sure I have one example of a two
      line bullet here for variety's sake.
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage} \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: result]

You may need to add an `after=\strut` option to that `itemize` if you find that it's too close to table rows you may add below it.  I've got more answers and links on [another answer of mine about removing space above and below `itemize` in a table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130906/1680).

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem- turns out I had an errant `\\` at the end of my final `\item`.

Looks like you also have an extra `\\` after `\end{itemize}` - try deleting it and see if that helps- worked for me!

Comment: The `\\` after `\end{itemize}` is needed to end the table row. Also, the OP has no `\\` after the final item, if the MWE is to be believed.