# For loop in tabular with multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, for-loop

Can I do this without adding a new line and then remove the new line? I would like to skip `\\[-0.4cm]`. It just feels wrong

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{forloop}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{a4paper, left=2.5mm, top=2.5mm,bottom=2.5mm,right=2.5mm}

\newcounter{i}
\newcommand{\mylineNewTwo}[1]{%
    \forloop{i}{0}{\value{i}<#1}%
    {%
    \\[-0.4cm]% is it possible to do this without this line??
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line1}\\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Line2\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line3}\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line4}\\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & Line5\\
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Line6L\hfill Line6R}\\
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5cm}@{}@{}p{6.8cm}@{}}
                \mylineNewTwo{10}
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5cm}@{}@{}p{6.8cm}@{}}
                \mylineNewTwo{10}
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5cm}@{}@{}p{6.8cm}@{}}
                \mylineNewTwo{10}
            \end{tabular}
        }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196856/completely-expandable-loop-macro-that-also-works-in-tabular