# Pipe input for table content is working odd

Tags: tables, input

I have following document:

```tex
\documentclass[parskip=half-]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell,xltabular}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\subsection{Test table}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|>{\ttfamily\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.6cm}|m{1.8cm}|X|}
    \caption{Table caption}
    \label{tab:test-table}\\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray}
    \thead{\textnormal{Col1}} & \thead{Col2} & \thead{Col3} & \thead{Col4}                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \multicolumn{4}{c}%
    {{\bfseries Table \thetable\ continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray}
    \thead{\textnormal{Col1}} & \thead{Col2} & \thead{Col3} & \thead{Col4}                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
    \endhead
    %\
    \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Table section}} \\ \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
    \input{|"./test.py"}
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm using an `\input` with pipe:
`\input{|"./test.py"}`

If the content of the `test.py` is:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print(r'\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Table section 2}} \\ \hline')
print(r'11 & 22 & 33 & 44 \\ \hline')
```

I get an error:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.1 ...llcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Table section 2}}
                                                   \\ \hline
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I swap two last lines in the python script, I don't get an error but the table has two extra vertical lines.

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python3

print(r'11 & 22 & 33 & 44 \\ \hline')
print(r'\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\cellcolor{lightgray}\textbf{Table section 2}} \\ \hline')
```

[image]

I generate pdf with: `latexmk -shell-escape -enable-pipes -pdf -halt-on-error test.tex`

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `\input` is not expandable and has... *issues*... when used in tabular-like environments. Related question [expansion - Completely expandable loop macro that also works in tabular - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196856/completely-expandable-loop-macro-that-also-works-in-tabular)

Comment: Try using the expandableinput command from [Misplaced \noalign error with \input in a table after the 2020 fall LaTeX release - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583927/misplaced-noalign-error-with-input-in-a-table-after-the-2020-fall-latex-releas) ... actually you need to remove the file_get_full_name there.

Comment: the "expandableinput" is working but for files only - not for the piped commands.

Comment: you could put the `\\ \hline` at the start of the input not the end (and adjust the outer document accordingly)

Comment: it's not working