# How to align first \item on baseline in tabular, using modified \baselinestretch

Tags: tables, beamer, itemize, line-spacing

In a beamer presentation (no `setspace`, no `enumitem`) I want to use an `itemize` environment inside the column of a `tabular`. I want the first `\item` to be displayed on the same baseline, as the first lines of the other columns. As described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283612/vertical-alignment-of-itemize-in-tabular), `\itemize` starts on a new line, so the correct way of achieving this is a verical shift of `-\baselineskip`. However, this doesn't work, if the `baselinestretch` is modified, e.g. by `\linespread{1.15}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\linespread{1.15}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{
\tikz[baseline=(#1.base), remember picture]{
\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};
}
}   

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[t]{Title}
        \begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.1\linewidth}p{0.8\linewidth}}
            \tikzmark{left}{left text b} & \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item \tikzmark{right}{b number 1} \\ (with possibly two lines) 
                \item number 2 
            \end{itemize}
        \end{tabular}
            \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{
            \draw[red, line width=0.05pt](left.south west)--(right.south east|-left.south west);
            \draw[blue](right.south east)--(right.south east|-left.south east);
            }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very easy solution to this while trying to reproduce the problem on a different machine: Somehow the problem is caused when the `baselinestretch` is modified in the preamble. Using

```
\AtBeginDocument{\linespread{1.15}}
```

instead of

```
\linespread{1.15}
```

to only change it inside the document solves the problem. Of course it would still be interesting to know why. Should the `baselinestretch` generally not be changed in the preamble?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a good idea not to modify low-level TeX directives such as `\linespread` and `\baselineskip` directly. Instead, consider loading the `setspace` package and issuing the instruction `\setstretch{1.15}`.

Turning to the immediate issue at hand, since 1/1.15=0.8696 or roughly 0.87, you may want to use `\vspace*{-0.87\baselineskip}` instead of `\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}` to align the first lines in the first and second columns of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: This is very interesting, the `\setstretch{1.15}` behaves like a `\linespread{1.15}` placed in the preamble, no matter where it is placed. But would the usage of `\linespread` inside the document not be the better solution? In this case I don't have to recalculate the distance if I change the `\linespread`..

Comment: @Ktree - An answer to your question -- whether using `\linespread{1.15}` is "better" than using the machinery of the `setspace` package -- depends importantly on what else may be in your document. As I said, I think it's prudent *not* to manipulate some of TeX's low-level macros directly.