# How to align first \item on baseline in tabular, using nested itemize environments

Tags: tables, beamer, itemize, line-spacing

In a beamer presentation (no `setspace`, no `enumitem`) I want to use an itemize environment inside the column of a tabular. I want the first `\item` to be displayed on the same baseline, as the first lines of the other columns. This question was originally asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283612/vertical-alignment-of-itemize-in-tabular), but as there occured different problems, I split the question. In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/284086/how-to-align-first-item-on-baseline-in-tabular-using-modified-baselinestretch) question I already figured out how it works with modified `linespread`. However, I can't manage to appropriately align the first `\item`, if the tabular itself is placed inside an `itemize` environment. Which would be the correct shift distance here? Note that the needed distance seems to change slightly when the level of nesting increases!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{
\tikz[baseline=(#1.base), remember picture]{
\node(#1)[inner sep=0pt]{#2};
}
}   

\begin{document}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{frame}{title}
    \begin{itemize}%
    \item level 1, 1
    \item 
    \begin{tabular}[t]{lp{0.8\linewidth}}
    \tikzmark{left}{level 1, 2} & \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \tikzmark{right}{level 2,1} \\ (with possibly two lines) 
        \item 
            \begin{tabular}[t]{lp{0.8\linewidth}}
                \tikzmark{left2}{level 2, 2} & \vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item \tikzmark{right2}{level 3,1} \\ (with possibly two lines) 
                    \item level 3, 2
                \end{itemize}
            \end{tabular}
    \end{itemize}
    \end{tabular}
    \end{itemize}
        \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{
        \draw[red, line width=0.05pt](left.south west)--(right.south east|-left.south west);
        }
        \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{
        \draw[red, line width=0.05pt](left2.south west)--(right2.south east|-left2.south west);
        }
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: nested tabulars and itemizes]

Answer (score 1):

The 1pt is the interlineskip and with `\rlap` the parbox has no real width

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}
        \begin{itemize}%
            \item level 1, 1
            \item level 1, 2 
            \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+1pt}
            \begin{itemize}
                    \item level 2, 1 \newline (with possibly two lines) 
                    \item level 2, 2
                     \rlap{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\vspace*{\dimexpr-\baselineskip+1pt}
                    \begin{itemize}
                        \item level 3, 1 \newline (with possibly two lines) 
                        \item level 3, 2
                    \end{itemize}}}% inner parbox
            \end{itemize}}}% outer parbox
        \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: where is the tikz code in your answer? If you look close, you will see that the lines are actually not perfectly aligned :( Moreover, if the 1pt is the interlineskip, shouldn't `\nointerlineskip` do the trick then? Doesn't work for me..

Comment: then `tikz` stuff was deleted. It is not important for the answer. "Doesn't work for me"  is not a useful description ...

Comment: by "Doesn't work for me" I mean that using `\nointerlineskip` has no effect, if I try it. This makes me think the 1pt actually doesn't come frome `interlineskip`. But anyway, it seems that `1pt` is just "something that is very close to the desired distance, but not the actual distance", as the lines are not perfectly aligned in your answer. Still I find the solution with `\parbox` instead of tabular interesting, I just think the problem still isn't really solved...