# Alignment of item number in list containing a minipage

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate, minipage

I would like to have the list number at the beginning of the item, and not centered as is the case for item (b) the example below. If I comment out the `\usepackage{nccmath}`, I get this, but then the spacing gets messed up. I'd rather keep the `nccmath` package if possible.

I also do need to keep the `[c]` for the minipages.

I have looked at [Preventing itemize environment to insert initial vertical space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6445/preventing-itemize-environment-to-insert-initial-vertical-space) and [Including an itemized list within a tabular column using the paralist package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10494/including-an-itemized-list-within-a-tabular-column-using-the-paralist-package), but can not get that to work for me.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{paralist} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} % Removing fixes vertical align, but changes spacing

\newcommand{\MyMiniPage}{
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0in}
  \begin{align*}
    a &= b\\
    c &= d
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0in}
  \begin{align*}
    y &= z
  \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item First item
  \item \MyMiniPage
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I attempted to use `\compress` as mentioned in the other posts above, but was not able to get it to work.

---------------- Revised posting using \input -------------

This is in the file ListsProblem-Minipage.tex:

```
\documentclass[preview=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0in}
    \begin{align*}
        a &= b\\
        c &= d
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c]{1.0in}
    \begin{align*}
        y &= z
    \end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This is in the file ListsProblem-Minipage2.tex:

```
\documentclass[preview=false,fleqn]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
%\begin{minipage}{3.0in}
\begin{align*}
                (-3)^4 &= 81\\
\frac{5^{23}} {5^{21}} &= 25
\end{align*}
%\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

And here is the main file:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{paralist} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} % Removing fixes align, but changes spacing
\begin{document}
\input{ListsProblem-Minipage.tex}  % These two correctly yields
\input{ListsProblem-Minipage.tex}  % the desired 4 columns

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item First item
    \item \input{ListsProblem-Minipage.tex}
    \item \input{ListsProblem-Minipage2.tex}  % not in a mini-page
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Note that the item label (b) is not aligned with the top of the two center aligned mini pages. The alignment of the (b) with the mini-pages that I want can be seen by commenting out the `\usepackage{nccmath}`. But I want a solution that does not require me to abandon the `nccmath` package.  Commeting this out also screws up the spacing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be solved with `\valign`

```
\newcommand{\MyMiniPage}{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{\hrule height 0pt \kern-\baselineskip
  \valign{\vfill##\vfill\cr
    \hbox to 1in{$\begin{aligned}
    a &= b\\
    c &= d
  \end{aligned}$\hfill}\cr
  \hbox to1in{$\begin{aligned}
    y &= z
  \end{aligned}$\hfill}\cr}}
}
```

I put everything into a `\vtop`, where I care to set the first line aligned with the `\item`; then it's just a "trivial" `\valign`. :)

--- **Added after having seen the example** ---

In the case of an included standalone file the approach is different:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{paralist}

\newcommand{\iteminput}[2][\topskip-1bp]{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{\hrule height 0pt\kern-\dimexpr#1\relax
    \input{#2}}}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} % Removing fixes align, but changes spacing
\begin{document}
\input{ListsProblem-Minipage.tex}  % These two correctly yields
\input{ListsProblem-Minipage.tex}  % the desired 4 columns

\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item First item
    \item \iteminput{ListsProblem-Minipage.tex}
    \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The command `\iteminput` has an optional argument in case the default back up in the `\vtop` is not correct

```
\iteminput[<dimension>]{filename}
```

Comment: This produces the output I want. But the two mini pages that I provided in my posting are coming from a standalone file and need to function as mini pages.  For example, if I say `\MyMiniPage \MyMiniPage` I do not get the expected behavior (which I do with the definition of MyMinipage that I gave in the post.

Comment: @Peter: please, provide a real example.

Comment: Above ex is close to real. To simplify posting, I defined a `newcommand{\MyMiniPage}`. In reality, contents of this command are in a separate standalone file MyMiniPage.tex, and the enumerate line reads `\item \input{MyMiniPage.tex}` instead of `\item \MyMiniPage`.  I need the contents of this file to behave as a mini-page (so for instance, 2 subsequent `\input{MyMiniPage.tex}` gives 4 columns center aligned as the above example does with `\MyMiniPage \MyMiniPage`. But when MyMiniPage.tex is included in a list, I want the top of the two (center aligned) mini-pages at the top of the list num.

Comment: Is it a problem to provide the code for the standalone files? It's impossible to try and give a solution, otherwise.

Comment: Standalone files now posted. I left the original code as well in case it is useful to someone else.

Comment: I like this! But, can it be made more general to top align the contents? Revised example above where I have a new file ListsProblem-Minipage2.tex which is just an align* (not a minipage). I'd rather not use different settings based on if the `\input` file is a `minipage` or just an `align`, or something else.

Comment: Also, is there a way to flush left the included content so it also aligns on the left? I added the [fleqn] option to the `\documentclass`, and that helps but doesn't move it all the way to the left.

Comment: You can say `\iteminput[\abovedisplayskip+\topskip]{ListsProblem-Minipage2.tex}` to get top alignment; if you want a flush left alignment, don't use `align*`, but rather `$\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}$`, because `align*` creates a full size object. In this case, however, the offset (i.e. the optional argument to \iteminput) must be guessed as there are too many possibilities: in the second example, for instance, the exponent creates a too high object to be covered with `\topskip`. I get alignment with `\iteminput[3ex]{ListsProblem-Minipage2.tex}`

Comment: I'l use this for now, but there has to be some method to auto-crop out the white space and align it left and top... This should work no matter what was in the external file.

Comment: @egreg: This has worked fine for a while, but am finding that it is not respecting the current `\linewidth`. I have posted a follow up question: [on how to adjust `\iteminput` defined here to respect the current `\linewidth` setting.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-adjust-macro-to-respect-current-linewidth)

Answer (score 1):

If you want it flush left, then simply use `$...$` lines of math code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{nccmath} % Removing fixes vertical align, but changes spacing

\newcommand{\MyMiniPage}{\arraycolsep=1.4pt
$\begin{array}{@{} l l @{\qquad} l l}
    a &= b   & y &=z \\[3pt]
    c &= d
  \end{array}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(a)]
  \item First item
  \item \MyMiniPage
  \item Third item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like the two minipages to be `[c]` aligned with each other. I just want the label of the second item `(b)` to be aligned with the top. Would also prefer to still use the the `nccmath` package, unless there is a problem with that package.

Comment: @Peter: see edited answer

Comment: Ok, guess I am not being very clear: I want the `(b)` at the top, AND the two mini-pages to be centered with respect to each other. The mini-pages are  coming from separate `standalone` files, but to simply the test case here I defined a command - both show exactly the same problem.  They really should remain as mini-pages as they don't always just have math in them. So, I need them to be mini-pages, centered with respect to each other. I just want the label at the top.