# How to adjust macro to respect current \linewidth?

Tags: macros, line-breaking, margins, minipage

I'm having issues with text going past the end of the specified `\textwidth`. I posted [this question about why text was being placed beyond the specified line width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18210/why-is-text-being-placed-beyond-the-specified-line-width). The MWE provided there produced situations similar to mine. Adding `\sloppy` fixed all the problems posted in that MWE, but when I used that in my larger document, it had absolutely no effect on the output.

Narrowing my problem down further, I see that the problem stems from the `\iteminput` macro which is a solution provided [to an issue related to the alignment of item number in a list containing a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/alignment-of-item-number-in-list-containing-a-minipage/16351) that was originating in a `standalone` file. I have been using this to input my files. This macro was necessitated by the fact that the imported `standlalone` files were not being aligned within enumerated lists.

It appears that `\iteminput` is ignoring that fact that the `\linewidth` has modified since it is now within an `enumerate` list. So, my question is: How do I adjust the `\iteminput` macro to respect the current `\linewidth`.

The MWE for this requires two files. The first file here is the `standalone` file called Item-from-File.tex:

```
\documentclass[preview=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{paralist}

% geometry settings identical to main file.
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.5in}
\geometry{bottom=0.5in}
\geometry{paperheight=11.0in}
\geometry{paperwidth=8.5in}
\geometry{textwidth=6.0in}
\geometry{left=1.125in}
\geometry{right=1.125in}
\geometry{showframe=true}

\begin{document}
  Here is a line of text, but one that is from a separate standalone file.
  This file typeset by itself is fine. When this is input into an enumerated list 
  via the normal input macro, things are also fine. But the text goes past the end
  of the line if input with modified input macros.
  %
  % Updated to include following:
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
     \item First item: If this sentence is long enough things are not so good when 
           this is included in another file. But things are fine in this standalone 
           file.
     \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
       \item First sub-item: If this sentence is long enough things are not so good 
             when this included in another file. But things are fine in this 
             standalone file.
     \end{enumerate}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

The second is the main document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone} % Needed for the standalone file
\usepackage{paralist}

% geometry settings identical to standalone file.
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=0.5in}
\geometry{bottom=0.5in}
\geometry{paperheight=11.0in}
\geometry{paperwidth=8.5in}
\geometry{textwidth=6.0in}
\geometry{left=1.125in}
\geometry{right=1.125in}
\geometry{showframe=true}

\newcommand{\iteminput}[2][\topskip-1bp]{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{\hrule height 0pt\kern-\dimexpr#1\relax
    \input{#2}}}


\begin{document}
Text in this file, things work great:
\begin{enumerate}
  \item When this text appears in the same file things are ok.
        The line goes to the end of the correct spot on the page and wraps around.
  \item \input{Item-from-File.tex}% This is ok
  \item \iteminput[2.5ex]{Item-from-File.tex}% This is a problem
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the desired line width to the macro.

```
\newcommand{\iteminput}[2][\topskip-1bp]{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{
    \hsize=\linewidth\hrule height 0pt\kern-\dimexpr#1\relax
    \input{#2}}}
```

---

As Frank Mittelbach points out in [another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65112/4427), adding `\@totalleftmargin=0pt` is necessary for avoiding bad indentation (the outer one is kept inside):

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\iteminput}[2][\topskip-1bp]{%
  \leavevmode\vtop{
    \hsize=\linewidth\hrule height 0pt\kern-\dimexpr#1\relax
    \@totalleftmargin=\z@
    \input{#2}}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to modify this so that the evaluation of \linewidth is deferred? I have updated the example to show the problem when there is an enumerated list in the input file.

Comment: @Peter: I get an error even without the `\iteminput` line.

Comment: List item 2 in [this](http://edge.imgur.com/9ecny.png) image uses just `\input` and it seems to work fine:

Comment: @Peter: There's something about paralist that I don't understand. If I don't load it in the main file, the enumerate in the input file gives an error.

Comment: I thought `paralist` was requried for the `enumerate` environment? It is needed in both files. I posted a related question: [what are the differences between using paralist vs enumitem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)

Comment: @egreg See [a followup question on vtop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/65088/2707) where Frank Mittelbach notes that using `\vtop` here is not going to interact well with the rest of the galley.  Perhaps you should update this answer to use `minipage` as he mentions.