# Using \vtop affects indentation of \intertext

Tags: horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I am using the `\iteminput` macro from the solution at [How to adjust macro to respect current \linewidth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-adjust-macro-to-respect-current-linewidth) to import content from other TeX files.  However, this appears to be effecting the indentation of text from `\intertext{}`.  The red text below is where the problem is.

When using the normal `\input` things work great and the text is left aligned as desired, as shown in (a). However, when using the `\iteminput` macro the `\intertext` is shifted to the right, as shown in (b):

[image]

I found out that if I remove the `\vtop{}` from the `\iteminput` macro, I get the desired behavior. But since this is from an *egreg* solution, I am reluctant to do that without knowing if that will result in some other problem.

### References:

- [How to adjust macro to respect current \linewidth?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-adjust-macro-to-respect-current-linewidth)
- [Top-aligning imported graphics](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-topgraph)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{xcolor}% to highlight the problem area in the output
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.tex}
    Two well known equations are:
    \begin{alignat*}{3}
        E & = mc^2 \\
        \intertext{\textcolor{red}{and}}
        F &= ma
    \end{alignat*}
\end{filecontents*}


\newcommand{\MyInput}[1]{%  
    \begingroup%           The grouping here is not currently causing a problem.
        \input{#1}%        But do need grouping here (for a unrelated reason).
    \endgroup%             
}%

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-adjust-macro-to-respect-current-linewidth/
\newcommand{\iteminput}[2][\topskip-1bp]{%
    \leavevmode%
    \vtop{%  Removing this fixs the problem.
        \hsize=\noexpand\linewidth\hrule height 0pt\kern-\dimexpr#1\relax%
        \MyInput{#2}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
    \item \input{foo}            % This works great
    \item \iteminput[2.5ex]{foo} % This shifts "and" to right!!
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: \noexpand\linewidth looks distinctly odd (and wasn't in egreg's version) as \linewidth is not expandable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Hmmm....Wonder where that came from?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that already the initial solution is wrong and in this particular situation it shows. `\vtop` is not a LaTeX command, so if you use it you need to fully understand what it does and what it doesn't.

The important part is what it doesn't: it doesn't set up a new box-galley that ignores any outer circumstances like being inside an enumerate. So that fact is still visible inside and `\intertext` therefore assumes it has to indent its text. However the text is already indented for the simple reason that the whole box is. So a quick fix **for your particular case only** would be

```
\makeatletter
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18247/how-to-adjust-macro-to-respect-current-linewidth/
\newcommand{\iteminput}[2][\topskip-1bp]{%
    \leavevmode%
    \vtop{%  Removing this fixs the problem.
        \hsize=\noexpand\linewidth\hrule height 0pt\kern-\dimexpr#1\relax%
       \@totalleftmargin\z@   % cancel any line indentation
        \MyInput{#2}%
    }%
}%
\makeatother
```

But for course this is not right either as we can see from looking at `\@arrayparboxrestore` to see what LaTeX is really resetting in such a case.

Bottom line, for a general solution, you are much better off to use a minipage environment (which would take care of all this as it is made to work with other LaTeX constructs). Alternatively you really have to work a lot harder to blend your command with the internals of LaTeX.