# nccmath affecting minipage widths

Tags: minipage, nccmath

It seems that `nccmath` is affecting the layout of minipages.   In the MWE,  you can see the left `minipage` is clearly not taking up 70% of the page as I wanted. I'm hoping that there is an easy fix for this, otherwise I need to get rid of `nccmath`.

I have had problems with `nccmath` previously as discussed in [Alignment of item number in list containing a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/alignment-of-item-number-in-list-containing-a-minipage) so I'm wondering if I should try to work without that package.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,preview=false]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}% Needed for fleqn environment

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.70\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    y &= x 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.30\linewidth}
    Note: abcd
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that **nccmath** indeed breaks minipages containing only a math display, setting them to have the width resulting from adding the space on the left of the display and the equation width.

If the minipage contains "paragraph material", its width is correctly set.

Solution: start a minipage that should contain only a display with

```
\hrule height 0pt width \hsize
```

Some examples (in the code the `\hrule` has a height in order to make it visible)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}% Needed for fleqn environment

\begin{document}
% let's have a "ruler"
\hbox to\hsize{\leaders\hrule\hskip0pt plus 7fill
  \kern-.2pt\vrule depth 2pt\kern-.2pt
  \leaders\hrule\hskip0pt plus 3fill}
\medskip

Example 1: we put a rule with the desired width

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.70\columnwidth}
\hrule width \hsize\kern-.4pt
\begin{align*}
    y &= x 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\columnwidth}
\hrule
    Note: abcd

Where should this go?
\hrule
\end{minipage}

\medskip

Example 2: we don't specify the rule's width

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.70\columnwidth}
\hrule\kern-.4pt
\begin{align*}
    y &= x 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\columnwidth}
\hrule
    Note: abcd

Where should this go?
\hrule
\end{minipage}

\medskip

Example 3: text before the display

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.70\columnwidth}
\hrule\kern-.4pt
Some text before
\begin{align*}
    y &= x 
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\columnwidth}
\hrule
    Note: abcd

Where should this go?
\hrule
\end{minipage}

\medskip

Example 4: text below the display

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.70\columnwidth}
\hrule\kern-.4pt
\begin{align*}
    y &= x 
\end{align*}
Some text below
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.30\columnwidth}
\hrule
    Note: abcd

Where should this go?
\hrule
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Do you see any problems with adding that `hrule` to all `minipages`?  Also, is the `\noindent` a good idea to add to all minipages?

Comment: The `\noindent` was *outside* the minipages, just not to have it added when building the line. Adding the `\hrule` to all minipages is definitely out of the question: you'll not be able to align at the top row.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, but I don't understand. I thought the above macro was adding a horizontal rule of zero height. If ALL `minipages` have that, then I can't understand why they would not be able to align at top.

Comment: Just try with one having ascenders and the other not.

Comment: Have posted another problem with nccmath where [minipage text overlaps with text before that](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22167/minipage-content-overlaps-with-text-before-that-if-nccmath-is-used)

Answer (score 4):

In the comment within your code I see you need `nccmath` for the `fleqn` environment. You can define that environment yourself in your preamble without loading `nccmath`. You can use the code from that package:

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment*{fleqn}[1][\z@]{\@fleqntrue
  \setlength\@mathmargin{#1}\ignorespaces
}{%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion. But, in case I need other things from `nccmath` later, I think I'll leave it in my common preamble.  Taking it out now and putting it back in seems that it might result in a lot of additional work later. Do you know if the features of `nccmath` package have been implemented elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The bug is due to `\NCC@ignorepar` command in `nccmath` package:

"This command removes extra vertical space before display formula if it starts from a new paragraph and changes the beforeskip to \abovedisplayshortskip if the \useshortskip command was applied."

`\let \NCC@ignorepar=\relax` should fix the problem.