# Aligning equations with using fleqn

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, amsmath

I use `fleqn` as a document class, but now I solve problem, how to align few equations to the center and few to the right.

I've tried `\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}` but after that is the problem that I can't use previously used `fleqn` aligning.

Could you help me with any solution?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: [Align equation left](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/145657/250119)
 has solutions that works locally as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think this is a good option since it makes your document inconsistent; that being said, you coud give a try to the [`nccmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath) package; declaring the `fleqn` package option you will have flushed left equations, and using the `ceqn` environment you can center some chosen equation(s):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
a &= b \\
&= c \\
&= d.
\end{align}

\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align}
a &= b \\
&= c \\
&= d.
\end{align}
\end{ceqn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks nice. But I have problem with my TeXworks. During the loading process TeXworks write me error message "! LaTeX Error: File `nccmath.sty' not found." So I saved "nccmath.sty" to my style folder but there is still the same problem.

Comment: Maybe will be better to write down my document setting.\documentclass[fleqn,a4paper,11pt]{article}
(\manypackages)
\usepackage{nccmath}

\begin{document}

Comment: @astrak I don't know which LaTeX distribution you are using, but here you find advise on installing packages for TeX Live http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73016/3954 and for MikTeX http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/3954

Comment: I found help in user guide of the nccmath package. Thank you very much for help!

Comment: @astrak: FYI, I used to use [the `nccmath` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath)
package but ran into numerous issues that I decided to drop it. See [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath). If all you want is the `felqn` environment, you can use 
Stefan Kottwitz's solution from [nccmath affecting minipage widths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22110/4301).

Comment: @PeterGrill The **nccmath** works for me without any erros, and I usually insert too many formulas.

Comment: @AndresMitre: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). The `nccmath` worked for me as well. But once I got futher into it problems arose -- see the linked questions in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you only require to locally disable the effect of the `fleqn` option (when using `amsmath`), you can just manually set the respective boolean to false:

```
{
    % Use grouping to keep effect local
    \makeatletter
    \setbool{@fleqn}{false}
    \makeatother

    \begin{equation}
        A = B
    \end{equation}
}
```

[Source](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=85542&sid=42d3d12d462be6e63bcee8a2a726fe08#p85542)