# Left alignment not working on array environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, arrays

I'm writing some math(s) stuff and wanted the equations to be on the left side of the document using the `array` environment inside `equation*`, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$t_n(x)$ is a function that truncates $x$ to the $n$-th digit
\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{l}
    t_n (x) \equiv \left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^n} \right\rfloor 10^n % This should be on the left
\end{array}\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

My other packages are `relsize`, `amsfonts` and `utf8 inputenc` (maybe they are interfering or something like that?) and I'm using Overleaf as my online compiler.

Thanks, M.T.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You misunderstood the use the option `l` in array: each row of the array will be left-aligned `w.r.t. the array`, but rhe array itself will centred. To get what you want, either use the `fleq` option of your document class (all equations will be  aligned on the left), or, for a punctual usage, use the `fleqn*` environment, from `amsmath`.

Comment: @Bernard I tried with `\documentclass[fleq]{article}`, but the following error appeard: `LaTeX Warning: Unused global option(s): [fleq].` and the `fleqn*` environment is undefined (yes, I'm using `amsmath`)

Comment: There was a typo in the option: it should have been `[fleqn]`. Sorry for not having checked. For the   environments `fleqn(*)`, I'm surprised: are you sure amsmath was loaded when you used the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all you equations to be left-aligned, then as Bernard says, you can use:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}



\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$t_n(x)$ is a function that truncates $x$ to the $n$-th digit
\begin{equation*}
    t_n (x) \equiv \left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^n} \right\rfloor 10^n % This should be on the left
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

If you want just a single equation flushed left then you can use

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage[fleqn]{nccmath}

\begin{document}
$t_n(x)$ is a function that truncates $x$ to the $n$-th digit
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation*}
    t_n (x) \equiv \left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^n} \right\rfloor 10^n % This should be on the left
\end{equation*}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

as explained in [the answer to another question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87549/aligning-equations-with-using-fleqn)

*** EDIT ***

In response to Bernard's comment, you can set the indentation distance as an optional argument to `\begin{fleqn}`, e.g. `\begin{fleqn}[1in]`.

Comment: Ok, I wanted it to work on single equations maintaining the `array` environment, but you can't always get what you want...

Comment: @JPi: I had forgotten the `fleqn` environment. Thanks for reminding me! You might want to mention  it accepts  the distance to the text left margin (`\displayindent`) as an optional argument.

Comment: @MassimilianoTron: you can still stick an array environment inside the `equation*` environment.  It just seemed redundant given that you only had a single formula and `array` is used for a matrix of expressions.