# Centering multiple boxed equations

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, equations

I want to center this following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\newcommand*\widebox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\newcommand*\rpos{\text{\textbf{r}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[box=\widebox]{align}
    \rpos&=x\,\hat{i}+y\,\hat{j}+z\,\hat{k},\nonumber\\
    \mathbf R &= (R_{\text{Terra}}+\text{h})\:\hat{k},\nonumber\\
    \bm{\mathcal R}&=\mathbf R + \rpos,\nonumber\\
    \bm{\omega}&=\omega(sin\lambda\:\hat{i}+cos\lambda\:\hat{k}).\nonumber\\ \nonumber
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the code centered in the box, or do you want the box centered across the line.  p.s.  Your code does not compile as is...please edit to make it compile.  Welcome to the site.

Comment: Remove the last `\\ \nonumber` to center the equations vertically in the box.

Comment: Or, to center horizontally, remove `fleqn` class option and use `gather*` instead of `align`. Also you should be using `align*` and then there'd be no need for `\nonumber`s.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I want the box to be centered across the line.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos  Thanks for the edit. But is there a way to supress the fleqn option just in this part of the code?

Comment: I don't know about that, I'll see and edit the answer if a workaround is found! `:D`

Comment: @J.Barbosa, I'm sorry but seems that you either use `empheq` without `fleqn` or you use `nccmath`'s **`ceqn`** environment in conjunction with `amsmath`. See [this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87549/aligning-equations-with-using-fleqn) for reference on the `nccmath` thing. I saw in `empheq` manual the `marginbox` for `fleqn` documents but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have unnumbered **horizontal aligned** equations remove the `fleqn` class option and use the `gather*` environment from `amsmath` without putting `&` alignment characters:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[overload]{empheq}

\newcommand*\widebox[1]{\fbox{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}
\newcommand*\rpos{\text{\textbf{r}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{empheq}[box=\widebox]{gather*}
    \rpos = x \, \hat{i} + y \, \hat{j} + z \, \hat{k}, \\
    \mathbf R = (R_{\text{Terra}} + \text{h}) \: \hat{k}, \\
    \bm{\mathcal R} = \mathbf R + \rpos, \\
    \bm{\omega} = \omega (\sin\lambda \: \hat{i}+ \cos\lambda\:\hat{k}). % Last '\\' is not placed!
    \end{empheq}
\end{document}
```

Notice that this is not usual equation aligment as the equations won't be aligned at the `=` sign. To align through equal sign **and** have unnumbered equations use the `align*` environment!

Also notice the use of `\sin` and `\cos` for proper upright sine and cosine functions.

[image]