# left align an alignedat environment

Tags: amsmath, flalign

now I am trying to get this output aligned to the left of my document

[image: Desired output]

This is the code that I am using to achieve it :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    \begin{alignedat}{10}
    &a &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+ c} &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+ f} &&\phantom{+ g} &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+}b &&\phantom{+ c} &&+ d &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+ f} &&\phantom{+ g} &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+} c &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+ f} &&+ g &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+}b &&\phantom{+ c} &&+ d &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+ f} &&\phantom{+ g} &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+ c} &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+} e &&\phantom{+ f} &&\phantom{+ g} &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+ c} &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+} f &&\phantom{+ g} &&+ h &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+} c &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+ f} &&+ g &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+ c} &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+} f &&\phantom{+ g} &&+ h &&\phantom{+ i} &&= 0 \\
    &\phantom{a} &&\phantom{+ b} &&\phantom{+ c} &&\phantom{+ d} &&\phantom{+ e} &&\phantom{+ f} &&\phantom{+ g} &&\phantom{+ h} &&\phantom{+} i &&= 0
    \end{alignedat}
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

This is what I am getting though :

[image: Output I'm getting]

Could you help me get it to the left of the page as desired?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Unrelated: ‘avec $0$ étant …`  is really bad style. Just write ‘$0$ étant …’.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't use `flalign` but I hope that it helps!

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
    a &   &   &    &   &   &    &    &   &=0 \\
      & b &   &+\;d&   &   &    &    &   &=0 \\
      &   & c &    &   &   &+\;g&    &   &=0 \\
      & b &   &+\;d&   &   &    &    &   &=0 \\
      &   &   &    & e &   &    &    &   &=0 \\
      &   &   &    &   & f &    &+\;h&   &=0 \\
      &   & c &    &   &   &+\;g&    &   &=0 \\
      &   &   &    &   & f &    &+\;h&   &=0 \\
      &   &   &    &   &   &    &    & i &=0
\end{array}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

One advantage of this is that you can use it in the same line with your text (though I don't use that advantage usually).

Comment: Wow, why was I giving myself so much trouble when this answer is simple yet so elegant  thank you so much for that answer.

Comment: @Sephya: FYI, The _correct_ binary operator spacing is given by `{}+x`, not `+\;d`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thank you very much! I haven't heard of that before 

Comment: @PeterGrill thanks for the tip, really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can easily left-align any display equations with the `\fleqn` environment from `nccmath`. An optional argument specifies at which distance the left margin the equations start (0pt by default).

I propose two solutions: one based on `alignat*`, with a simpler code, and another, with the `systeme` package – probably the simplest  possible syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{systeme} 

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
     \begin{alignat*}{10}
    & a & \phantom{{}+{}} & &\phantom{{}+{}} & & & &\phantom{{}+{}}& &\phantom{{}+{}}& & & &\phantom{{}+{}} & &\phantom{{}+{}}& & & = 0 \\
    & & & b & & & &+ d & & & & & & & & & & & & = 0 \\
    & & & & & c & & & & & & & & + g & & & & & &= 0 \\
    & & & b & & & &+ d & & & & & & & & & & & & = 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & e & & & & & & & & & & = 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & f & & & & + h & & & & = 0 \\
    & & & & & c & & & & & & & & + g & & & & & & = 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & f & & & & + h & & & & = 0 \\
    & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & & i & = 0
    \end{alignat*}

    \sysdelim..
    \systeme{a = 0, \phantom{+}b + d = 0, \phantom{+}c + g = 0, b + d = 0, \phantom{+}e = 0, \phantom{+}f + h = 0, c + g = 0, f + h = 0, \phantom{+} i = 0}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image: An optional argument lets you choose]

Comment: FYI, I used to use [the `nccmath` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nccmath)
package but ran into numerous issues that I decided to drop it. See [Is there a replacement for nccmath?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22170/is-there-a-replacement-for-nccmath) and the problems listed in the question. If all you want is the `fleqn` environment, you can use 
Stefan Kottwitz's solution from [nccmath affecting minipage widths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22110/4301).

Comment: I personally never met a problem with nccmath, but I rarely use  minipages. I use  this package mainly for its medium-sized fractions (and formulæ, more generally) and its useful `\useshortskip` command.