# Vertical Alignment of (graphic+text, inside a mini page)+item number

Tags: graphics, lists, vertical-alignment, minipage

I have a figure and text inside a `minipage` inside an `enumerate`. I would like align the text and the `item` number and  top-align the figure and the text.

Top top-align figures and text in the past I have used the `\vspace{0pt}` solution mentioned in [Aligning image and text on top, with minipages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11630/aligning-image-and-text-on-top-with-minipages)  but this fails to align with the `item` number.

This question seems relevant: [Alignment of item number in list containing a minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15801/alignment-of-item-number-in-list-containing-a-minipage)
I have tried and failed to adapt egreg's solution. I would also prefer not do define a whole new minipage environment, if possible.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\paragraph{Ludwig Boltzmann (1844~V1906)}\par
He was an Austrian physicist famous for his founding contributions in the
fields of statistical mechanics and statistical thermodynamics. He was
one of the most important advocates for atomic theory at a time when that
scientific model was still highly controversial.
\end{minipage}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.2\linewidth}
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}
  \rule{\textwidth}{3cm}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\linewidth}
  \paragraph{Ludwig Boltzmann (1844~V1906)}\par
  He was an Austrian physicist famous for his founding contributions in the
  fields of statistical mechanics and statistical thermodynamics. He was
  one of the most important advocates for atomic theory at a time when that
  scientific model was still highly controversial.
\end{minipage}
\item
\item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\vspace{0pt}` is a nice trick which allows the two `minipage`s to be aligned on their first line.  But when you're doing that, you're creating an empty first ilne for the alignment to occur on.

So, my approach here is to use `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` in the `minipage` for the figure to create an empty first line and then insert a negative space.  The second `minipage` is just left as you would *normally* write it.  Thus for the second `minipage` you get the correct alignment with the `\item`.

Comment: Well, that was easy!

Comment: @ChrisChudzicki There's a `\par` after the `\paragraph` that doesn't appear to be doing anything. What was your intention?

Comment: @GeoffPointer Hmmm, I don't know why it's there. That example isn't mine, it's borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11630/27666