# enumerate list embedded in table with custom label

Tags: tables, enumerate, labels

I'd like to augment the embedded enumerated list inside tabular to have custom labels.  I am using [Yiannis Lazarides's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/how-to-include-enumerate-in-tabular)  tabular example, but would like to add a custom label that can do circled number as in [Stefan Kottwitz's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7032/good-way-to-make-textcircled-numbers) solution

So combined, this is what I'm trying to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\newcommand*\numcircledtikz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!h] 
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{.8\textwidth} | p{.2\textwidth} } 
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\height\relax}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{test}}
    &
    \begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\numcircledtikz{\arabic*}]
        \item ext steps\ldots
        \item num. circled  
        \end{enumerate}\\       
\end{tabular}\end{minipage}\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And this is the error messages I get:

> ```
> ! Missing number, treated as zero. <to be read again> 
>                \c@*  l.62 ...e}[label=\protect\numcircledtikz{\arabic*}
>                                               ] ?
> ```

When I try something more simple `[label=\textcircled{\arabic*}]`, I get the same error message.  How should I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a *complete* example of your actual code, it's difficult to see where the problem might be. However, this works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\numcircledtikz[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|}
\hline
\textbf{Name:} Foo \\
\hline
\textbf{Main success scenario:}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\protect\numcircledtikz{\arabic*}]
  \item [\numcircledtikz{1}]Entry action
  \item Next steps\ldots
\end{enumerate}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought I had in my preamble `\usepackage{enumitem}` but I did not.  So after checking that, now the code works. Thank you.