# Decrease spacing between lines of paragraph in longtable.

Tags: longtable, line-spacing

I used the suggestion from [Adding row spacing to a longtable?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135593/adding-row-spacing-to-a-longtable) to decrease the row spacing in my longtable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
\begin{longtable}{ l | l | l }
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & a small phrase
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: Example screenshot of working code]

But if I have a `p` column

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
\begin{longtable}{ l | l | p{5 cm} }
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & here is a long sentence which wraps to the next line \\
    a & b & a small phrase
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The spacing between the lines of the paragraph doesn't get reduced.

[image: Example screenshot of problem]

How can I also reduce the spacing between the paragraph lines?

I also read [Longtable with multicolumn and parbox spacing issues](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119304/longtable-with-multicolumn-and-parbox-spacing-issues), but the example was so complex, I wasn't sure whether the problem was the same at all.

Comment: The line spacing wasn't reduced because it is not related to `\arraystretch`. `:)` Maybe `\linespread{<value>}` could be of use, but I'm not too keen on this table layout.

Comment: Do you have serious reasons to decrease rowspacing. Generally, latex tables are considered having a very tight spacing, and can easily be hard to read.

Comment: @Bernard My actual table covers three pages with the default `longtable` spacing. I thought imitating the default spacing of `tabular` would make it more compact and easier to scan.

Comment: @Cecilia: Another solution consists in reducing the font size to, say, `\footnotesize`. Inside a paragraph cell, use `\linespread{…}`as mantioned by @Paulo Cereda, or (perhaps better) `\setstretch{…}`, from the `setspace` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also set line spacing locally in a clean way as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{.7}
\begin{longtable}{ l | l | p{5 cm} }
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & here is a long sentence which wraps to the next line, here is a long sentence which wraps to the next line \\
    a & b & a small phrase
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this solution best because I can use the spacing 1.0 and get exactly the same spacing as the rest of the document.  I don't have to figure out the conversion for the default longtable row spacing.

Comment: Neat. What if ``\begin{spacing}{0}`` is not tight enough? Negative values don't do anything...

Answer (score 4):

For some reason I didn't like the output of the setspacing package, and struggled to find that simply modifying `\baselineskip` would do. Maybe this can help people in the future:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array} %<================= Added this

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.7}
\begin{longtable}{ l | l | >{\baselineskip=10pt}p{5 cm} }
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & a small phrase \\
    a & b & here is a long sentence which wraps to the next line \\
    a & b & a small phrase
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

The notation `>{declaration}` add declaration before every instance of the `p{}` column. Also, notice that I added the `array` package.

Comment: Very neat. You can also define a column type like so (for instance): ``\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\flushleft\arraybackslash}>{\baselineskip=0pt}p{#1}}`` Sadly it won't take negative spacing and, for some reason, zero spacing is not tight enough for me...