# Long Tables with LaTEX

Tags: longtable

When I constructed my code with Latex, the output of the table seemed as follows. I need this table to fit each page correctly. How should I proceed?[image]

Comment: you did not show a MWE. But for long tables I recommend `longtable` package. There are other packages also for making tables than spread over multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I did use that package, and still shows up like this

Comment: Wlcome to TeX.SX. A table cannot be broken within a single cell. Seems your first column is one *giant* cell.Get rid of the vertical lines and have a look at `booktabs`. You will get great results.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119304/longtable-with-multicolumn-and-parbox-spacing-issues

Comment: I tried the code in the above comment and found out that a giant cell can be broken down. But I'm finding it difficult to compare this code with mine to do the required changes. Could anyone please clarify which line/lines made the table to be broken?

Comment: How can anyone tell you how to fix code that you have not shown? It is impossible to debug just from a screenshot, make a small but complete document that is an example of the problem and add it to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I meant is NOT from MY code, but in the code in this LINK. I need to capture which code line / lines do that. Thanks for the comment

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119304/longtable-with-multicolumn-and-parbox-spacing-issues

Here's the link again

Comment: longtable allows page breaks at each row of the table so there are no specific lines to point to in that link, that is just the expected (and only) behaviour of the package. You have shown an image of a bad break, so probably there is something wrong in your document source but impossible to guess what.

Comment: but I would guess you have multirow elements on the left columns, I would start by removing those and just having normal entries, the multirow entries interact badly with page breaking. I would also remove the vertical rules (longtable supports them but they are never pretty)