# 2 tables in document - error message 'Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabularx}'

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have two tables in my document but when I compile I get the error message

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end{tabularx}

When compiling the document with only one table there is no problem. When compiling document with both tables there is an error message but I can see both tables.

It looks like `enumerate` can cause problems. I have tried to follow suggestions from [TEX link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11541/how-to-include-enumerate-in-tabular) but with no success.

Can someone suggest a way to resolve the error please?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx, epstopdf}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
%\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}%Allows you to permanently fix figures. 
\usepackage{titleps}%fancy page borders? 
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}%this changes the page geometry i.e. margins left, right, top and bottom
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{SIunits}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption, makecell}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, ltablex}
\usepackage{caption}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}

\usepackage{enumitem}   % <--- added
\usepackage{etoolbox}   % <--- added
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,     % <--- added
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *         ,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
        \label{table:comparison of techniques}
        \small
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                X
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
                X
                @{}}
            \toprule
            \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
            \midrule
            Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
            &   Access and account set up
            &   \begin{enumerate}
                \item   Teast A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

                Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
                \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \end{enumerate}     \\
            \addlinespace
            Evaluate the ease in learning to map
            &   Learning how to map
            &   Read tutorial   \\
            \addlinespace
            Contribute data
            &   Contributing data by classifying maps
            &   \begin{enumerate}
                \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
                \item Test A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

                Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
                \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
            \end{enumerate}     \\
            \addlinespace
            Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
            & -- & --                   \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}%
    \end{table}

\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
    \small
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            >{\columncolor{red!30}} l
            *{3}{X}X@{}
        }\caption{}
        %\label{table:comparison of techniques}
        \\
        \Xhline{1pt}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
        &\bfseries{Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals?}{\cellcolor{red!30}} &\bfseries{Is the action visible?}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
        & \bfseries{Will the user recognise the action as the right one?}{\cellcolor{red!30}} &\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red!30}[6pt][0pt]\bfseries}c@{}}{\Centerstack{Will the user understand \\ the feedback?}} \\
        \Xhline{0.25pt}
        \endfirsthead
        \Xhline{1pt}
        % \rowcolor{red!30}
        \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
        &\bfseries{Is the effect of the current action the same as the user's goals?} &\bfseries{Is the action visible?}
        & \bfseries{Will the user recognise the action as the right one?} &\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}c@{}}{\Centerstack{Will the user understand \\ the feedback?}} \\
        \Xhline{0.25pt}
        \endhead
        \Xhline{0.25pt}
        \endfoot
        \Xhline{1pt}
        \endlastfoot
        \rowcolor{black}
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Task 1 - access and account set up}} \\
        Heading
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT.   
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT. \\
        \Xhline{0.25pt}
        Heading
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT.   
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT. \\
        \rowcolor{black}
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Task 2 - learning how to map}} \\*
        Heading 
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT.   
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT. \\
        \rowcolor{black}
        \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Task 3 - contributing data by classifying maps}} \\
        Heading
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT.   
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT. \\
        \Xhline{0.25pt}
        Heading
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT.   
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT. \\
        \Xhline{0.25pt}
        Heading
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT.   
        & TEXT. 
        & TEXT. \\
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11541/15925 .  You can not (easily) put an enumerate in a variable width column

Comment: @andrew: Thanks for the link. I tried the suggestions but no success. I may have been changing the wrong part of the code though. Are you able to advise, from my code, which section I should change please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out my original diagnosis, blaming the `X` column for not being to take an `enumerate` was not correct.  The problem is the `ltablex` package, and the solution is to issue its directive `\keepXColumns`.  The following document is minimal demonstrating the problem; without the `\keepXColumns` macro, it produces the missing `\item` error that you report, with the macro, it compiles fine.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ltablex}
\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{.9\textwidth}{X}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Test.
  \item Test.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Without `\keepXColumns`, the package `ltablex` tries to convert `X` columns to `l` columns if there is enough space.  This involves the package running some trial code, and that code does not fit well with an `enumerate` environment in the cell.

Adding `\keepXColumns` to your posted coded lets it compile fine.  However, your code contains many packages loaded twice and is longer than needed.  Here is a shorter version:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[main=british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3.5cm, bottom=3.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titleps,microtype,setspace,amsmath,SIunits,tabularx}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,makecell,ltablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape,afterpage}
\onehalfspacing

\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[enumerate]{nosep,
        topsep     = 0pt,
        partopsep  = 0pt,
        leftmargin = *,
        before     = \vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},
        after      = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
}}

\keepXColumns

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
  \caption{Cognitive walkthrough goals, tasks and actions}
  \label{table:comparison of techniques}
  \small
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
    X
    >{\centering\arraybackslash}X  % content of `X` column is now centered
    X
    @{}}
    \toprule
    \thead{\textbf{Goal}}& \thead{\textbf{Task}} & \thead{\textbf{Action}} \\
    \midrule
    Evaluate the ease in which users can join projects
    &   Access and account set up
    &   \begin{enumerate}
    \item   Teast A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

      Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
    \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
    \end{enumerate}     \\
    \addlinespace
    Evaluate the ease in learning to map
    &   Learning how to map
    &   Read tutorial   \\
    \addlinespace
    Contribute data
    &   Contributing data by classifying maps
    &   \begin{enumerate}
    \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
    \item Test A: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.

      Test B: Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
    \item Video provides a powerful way to help you prove your point.
    \end{enumerate}     \\
    \addlinespace
    Evaluate if the user likes using the application and whether they like using it
    & -- & --                   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{landscape}% Landscape page
  \small
  \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
    >{\columncolor{red!30}} l
    *{3}{X}X@{}
    }\caption{}
    % \label{table:comparison of techniques}
    \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
    &\bfseries{Is the effect of the current action the same as the
    user's goals?}{\cellcolor{red!30}} &\bfseries{Is the action
    visible?}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
    & \bfseries{Will the user recognise the action as the right
    one?}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
    &\multicolumn{1}{>{\columncolor{red!30}[6pt][0pt]\bfseries}c@{}}{\Centerstack{Will
    the user understand \\ the feedback?}} \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
    \endfirsthead
    \Xhline{1pt}
    % \rowcolor{red!30}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
    &\bfseries{Is the effect of the current action the same as the
    user's goals?} &\bfseries{Is the action visible?}
    & \bfseries{Will the user recognise the action as the right one?}
    &\multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}c@{}}{\Centerstack{Will the user
    understand \\ the feedback?}} \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
    \endhead
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
    \endfoot
    \Xhline{1pt}
    \endlastfoot
    \rowcolor{black}
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Task 1 - access and
    account set up}} \\
    Heading
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT. \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
    Heading
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT. \\
    \rowcolor{black}
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Task 2 - learning how to map}} \\*
    Heading
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT. \\
    \rowcolor{black}
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries Task 3 -
    contributing data by classifying maps}} \\
    Heading
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT. \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
    Heading
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT. \\
    \Xhline{0.25pt}
    Heading
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT.
    & TEXT. \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

- `color` package removed, already covered by `xcolor`
- `epstopdf` package removed, loaded by `graphicx` if necessary anyway
- `[main=british]` specification rather than juts `[british]` for `babel`
- load `geometry`, `booktabs`, `caption`, `makecell`, `pdflscape`, `afterpage` only once

You should look at using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` instead of `mathptmx` package; they offer better choices of glyphs with better spacing in mathematics and closer fit to the text fonts, and provide some more flexibility.

Comment: Thanks! The code works perfectly and thanks for the additional advice!

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!