# How should one use \write18 with BibTeX

Tags: subdividing, shell-escape, bibunits

**Background**
Now that TeX Live 2010 has a restricted `\write18`, I figured it'd be reasonable to update my cv which uses the `bibunits` package to run BibTeX for each of the `.aux` files.

Currently, I have a macro `\pubs` that typesets a label and then the bibliography (`\pubs` is used inside a `cvlist` environment from `currvita`, but that is not important here).

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pubs[2]{%
        \item[#1]
        \begin{bibunit}%
                \nocite{#2}%
                \putbib
        \end{bibunit}%
        \IfFileExists{\@bibunitname.bbl}{}
                {Run \texttt{bibtex \@bibunitname}}%
}
\makeatother
```

It is used like `\pubs{Refereed papers}{foo,bar,baz}` to typeset the bibliography entries corresponding to the citation keys foo, bar, and baz (or it prints a helpful message if BibTeX hasn't been run).

**Question**
How can I modify this to run `bibtex \@bibunitname` and then use the results in a sane way?

One idea I had that mostly works is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\pubs[2]{%
        \item[#1]
        \begin{bibunit}%
                \nocite{#2}%
                \immediate\write\@bibunitaux{\string\bibdata{\bu@bibdata}}%
        \end{bibunit}%
        \immediate\write18{bibtex \@bibunitname}%
        \InputIfFileExists{\@bibunitname.bbl}{}
                {Run \texttt{bibtex \@bibunitname}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Here the `\putbib` has been replaced with a write of the `\bibdata` and `\IfFileExists` has become `\InputIfFileExists`. **When run, this complains that all of my citations are undefined, but the output looks fine.** In particular, all of the aux files are closed before they are read in from the `\InputIfFileExists`.

Comment: If your general aim is an easy workflow when compiling a LaTeX document with multiple bibliographies, you may want to switch from bibunits/bibtex to biblatex/biber. Since v0.5.4, biber will handle multiple bibliographies in a single pass. (And biber installation is now quite easy, as "ready" binaries for Linux, Windows and Mac are available.)

Comment: @lockstep: I'm deleting all my comments, and have "archived" this discussion on meta.  It might be nice if you deleted your comments (besides maybe the first); the meta thread is at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597/comment-overflow-lockstep-and-i-argue-about-biblatex

Comment: Yet another non-answer: You might consider using rubber. I do not know about bibunits, but [rubber works well with multibib](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae/909#909). In particular, it does dependency-tracking correctly; for example, it runs Bibtex if *.bbl is older than your *.bib database.

Answer (score 3):

After I wrote this answer I realised it's not exactly what you're trying to do. Ohwell Without looking into `bibunits`, my guess is that you need to wait until after the aux files are closed before you run `bibtex`. Here's a hack to do it for the main document class:

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\end@doc@hook\@enddocumenthook
\def\@enddocumenthook#1\@@end{
  \end@doc@hook
  #1
  \immediate\write18{echo "^^J^^JCompiling bibliography with BibTeX:^^J" && bibtex \jobname && echo "^^JEnd BibTeX processing^^J"}
  \@@end
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\cite{whole-set}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As a big proponent of [PerlTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/perltex/), I posted a blurb on another [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/what-analysis-of-texlives-restricted-permissions-model-existscode) which I am going to shamelessly quote here:

> I know this isn't an answer to the
>   question, but perhaps could help you
>   with your problem. PerlTeX allows you
>   to embed Perl code as a LaTeX
>   function. When compiling if you use
>   `perltex --nosafe myfile.tex` then the
>   perl process has free reign to call
>   system functions. I'm not sure if this
>   could help your problem (because of an
>   order of operations, though if
>   \write18 would work at compile time
>   then this should), but it is a way to
>   get full access to your system as well
>   as other benefits of using inline Perl
>   code in your source.code in your source.