# Writing a CV in LaTeX

Tags: templates, resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Hello!
Could you tell is there any example (or maybe free template) of well-formed cv (preferably programmer cv) in LaTeX?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae?