# Link formatting: colors, underlines in moderncv

Tags: hyperref, color, links, moderncv

Following [the excellent advice in this site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae/89#89), I have started using [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/) for writing the new version of my CV.

Unfortunately, after converting to PDF, my http links work (clicking on them leads to the site), but they are formatted as normal text without underline and blue color.

Following some searches, I've tried:

```
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue} 
\href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{wikibooks home}
```

And some other tags, but nothing seems to work. Any idea how to format the links?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{Adam}
\familyname{Matan}
\email{adam@matan.name}                      % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.matan.name}                % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Professional network}

% ********************************************
% ***********      Link part       *********** 
% ********************************************

\cvline{Linkedin.com}        {\small \href{http://www.linkedin.com/in/adamatan}             {Adam Matan}   - Professional profile and links.    }
\cvline{Stackoverflow.com}   {\small \href{http://stackoverflow.com/users/51197/adam-matan} {Adam Matan}   - My software questions and answers. } 
\cvline{twitter.com}         {\small \href{http://twitter.com/justnoticed}                  {@justnoticed} - My tech tweets.}

% ********************************************
% ***********     /Link part       *********** 
% ********************************************

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-} % change the symbol for lists
% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}% for BibTeX numerical labels
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}       % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post an MWE?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That is because `moderncv.cls` sets `pdfborder` to `0 0 0` at the beginning of the document; here's the relevant code:

```
\AtEndPreamble{
  \@ifpackageloaded{CJK}
    {\RequirePackage[CJKbookmarks]{hyperref}}
    {\RequirePackage[pdftex]{hyperref}}
  \AtBeginDocument{
    \hypersetup{
      breaklinks,
      baseurl       = http://,
      pdfborder     = 0 0 0,
      pdfpagemode   = UseNone,% do not show thumbnails or bookmarks on opening
%      pdfstartview  = FitH,
      pdfstartpage  = 1,
      pdfcreator    = \LaTeX{} with `moderncv' package,
      pdfproducer   = \LaTeX{},
      bookmarksopen = true,
      pdfauthor     = \@firstname~\@familyname,
      pdftitle      = \@title,
      pdfsubject    = \@firstname~\@familyname,
      pdfkeywords   = \@firstname~\@familyname{} curriculum vit\ae{}}}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}% has to be issued after loading hyperref
}
```

EDIT: now I understand the request a little bit better (I hope); initially I thought that *all* the urls should have a colored border and I proposed some solution, now I see that it's just about *some* urls being colored. Taking this into account, I offer another solution:

I defined a new command `\Colorhref` with one optional argument (the color for the urls, default=`cyan`) and two mandatory arguments that will be passed to the standard `\href` command (`\Colorhref` also takes care of the change in font size). In your document you can use `\Colorhref` if you want your url with color and `\href` otherwise. Use the standard `moderncv` class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\firstname{Adam}
\familyname{Matan}
\email{adam@matan.name}
\homepage{www.matan.name}

\newcommand\Colorhref[3][cyan]{\href{#2}{\small\color{#1}#3}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Professional network}

\cvline{Linkedin.com}        {\Colorhref{http://www.linkedin.com/in/adamatan}             {Adam Matan}   - Professional profile and links.    }
\cvline{Stackoverflow.com}   {\small\href{http://stackoverflow.com/users/51197/adam-matan} {Adam Matan}   - My software questions and answers. } 
\cvline{twitter.com}         {\Colorhref[red]{http://twitter.com/justnoticed}{@justnoticed} - My tech tweets.}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result of the compilation of the above example code:

[image]

Comment: Great! and if I want to use both styles (underline some links but not all) - should I copy the paragraph and give it another name (e.g. `myhypersetup`)?

Comment: @Adam Matan: do you want to apply a border to the links of one category and to remove the border from the links from another category? I mean, for example, should all urls have borders but all citations remain borderless? Or some urls will have borders and some urls won't.

Comment: I want to have some of the URLS with cyan color (not borders), and some without. My current solution is using `\textcolor{cyan}` before the link.

Comment: @Adam Matan: I've added (in the EDIT of my answer) a new solution that (I think) does what you want, and doesn't involve editing `moderncv.cls`. Please, let me know if this new approach solves your problem, so I can delete my previous solution.

Answer (score 17):

`moderncv` does its `hyperref` setup at the beginning of the document (because only there can it use personal information such as `\firstname`), so the most elegant solution in my opinion is to do the same, e.g.

```
\AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 1,linkcolor=blue}}
```

That way, there is no need to define custom commands.

Comment: it should probably be: \AtBeginDocument{\hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 1,linkcolor=blue}}

Comment: To automatically use the color from the active moderncv template, refer to `color1` in the `\hypersetyp`.

Answer (score 10):

Goodness, the other answers are way too long or complicated.

The OP answered his own question in a comment (and it was the solution I was looking for). You can just change the properties of the text, which seems super obvious now that I think about it. Here is how you can color the link:

```
\textcolor{cyan}{\href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{wikibooks home}}
```

[image]

Similarly, you can underline the text using:

```
\underline{\href{http://www.wikibooks.org}{wikibooks home}}
```

[image]

The other answers are fine, but I'm just providing the simplest solution that resolved my problem.

Comment: So your suggesting is to colour the links individually with `\textcolor` rather than the other suggestions to update it globally. Also, consider the difference between your `wikibooks home` and (say) `wikiboogs home` as the hyperlink text. The latter doesn't have a descender. Moreover, `\underline` doesn't allow line breaks (although it might not be needed here).

Comment: Yes, this worked best for me because I only needed to insert a couple of hyperlinks into my document. Plus the OP also mentioned he wanted some of the hyperlinks to be different colors or have other effects. If someone has many hyperlinks in their document, then it would perhaps be simpler to follow one of the other answers. With respect to descenders (good question btw!), that's a separate issue having to do with `\underline` alone, and that's been addressed  [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/underline-omitting-the-descenders/67008#67008)

Comment: hi @unami best answer ever. brilliant.

Comment: glad I could help!