# Using \ref in moderncv class

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, moderncv

I have use the `\ref` function to make an internal reference to another section with `\label` and `\ref{}` but my reference is invisible but click able.

Someone has the same problem?

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP: Strange indeed. Here's a MWE (and yes, there's a click able link):

```
\documentclass{moderncv}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Master thesis}\label{sec:th}
\cvline{title}{\emph{Title}}

\section{Experience}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{See section \ref{sec:th}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from http://crypto.stackexchange.com. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question. Also, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Actually, it was first posted on Stack Overflow, and wrongly migrated to Cryptography because of me flagging it wrong (mis-click). Sorry.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: As per [link formatting colors underlines in cv](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/link-formatting-colors-underlines-in-cv) I can get the box to show up with `hypersetup{pdfborder = 0 0 1}` after `\begin{document}`, but this is not very useful to symbolize a link.

Comment: But, what should the now invisible link contain to make it visible? Sections in `moderncv` don't produce numbering, so there's no string to be picked up to generate a reference; they just contain `\phantomsection` to create an anchor.

Answer (score 3):

The [`moderncv` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) defines a section *without* a counter. Here's the `\section` command extracted from [`moderncv.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/moderncv.cls):

```
% usage: \section{<title>}
\newcommand*{\section}[1]{%
  \vspace*{2.5ex}%
  \parbox[m]{\hintscolumnwidth}{\raggedleft\hintfont{\color{sectionrectanglecolor}\rule{\hintscolumnwidth}{1ex}}}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
  \hspace{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
  \parbox[m]{\maincolumnwidth}{\sectionstyle{#1}}%
  \par\nobreak\vskip 1ex\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
```

Correct referencing is obtained via [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)'s `\phantomsection`. Hence, `\ref` returns nothing other than a correct internal hyperlink. This is also evident from the fact that the sections in `moderncv` is not typeset with a numbered counter.

As such, if you want to have a description associated with the link, you need to use `\hyperref[<lab>]{<text>}` where `<lab>` is your label, and `<text>` is what you want to be clickable. For example, using the posted MWE, you could use

```
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{See section \hyperref[sec:th]{Master thesis}}
```

[image]