# Refer to Numbered Section in moderncv Class using \ref

Tags: numbering, labels, moderncv, ref

I would like to refer back to a numbered section in the `moderncv` class using `\ref` but I am unable to do so.

I read the post titled 
[Using \ref in moderncv class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/using-ref-in-moderncv-class)
and I was able to get the following:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{secnumber}
\newcommand{\numbersec}{\refstepcounter{secnumber}\thesecnumber~}
\patchcmd{\section}{\sectionstyle{#1}}{\sectionstyle{\numbersec #1}}{}{}

\renewcommand\sectionstyle[1]{{%
  \refstepcounter{secnumber}%
  \sectionfont
  \textcolor{color1}{\thesecnumber.\quad#1}%
}}

\firstname{First Name}
\familyname{Last Name}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{A Section}
\label{sec.one}
Text goes here 

\section{Another Section}
\label{sec.two}
Text goes here 

\section{Yet Another Section}
\label{sec.three}

Recall in section \ref{sec.one} that we mentioned ...

\end{document}
```

This provides the following output:

[image]

As we can see, the section number is not appearing in the position where I use the `\ref` command.

I attempted to solve this issue by reading the post titled [Using \ref in moderncv class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32223/using-ref-in-moderncv-class)
however I was not successful.

Is it possible to use `\ref` and refer back to a numbered section which has been labelled in the `moderncv` class?

**Note:** I realize this might be an unusual request, however the reason for asking this question is because I have already have CV made using the `moderncv` class and I need to also write a supplementary document which requires numbered sections. I would like to use the `moderncv` class (with modifications) for this supplementary document in order to maintain visual and styling consistency between the CV and supplementary document. The reason for requiring referencing in the supplementary document is to avoid repeating information by requesting the reader to refer back to a certain numbered section.

Comment: Put the `\label` commands *inside* the `\section{...}`.  See [Understanding how references and labels work](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280) for an explanation why.

Comment: @AlanMunn, Thank you! That worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the rather convoluted code used to produce the number. If we simplify that code, then the `\label` commands will work as you would expect them to do.  Instead of incrementing the counter inside the `\sectionstyle` macro, we prepend it to the `\section` command. This allows the label to be accessed properly whether the `\label` command is inside the `\section{...}` command (as I suggested in my comment) or immediately after it (as you would expect it to work.)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcounter{secnumber}
\pretocmd{\section}{\refstepcounter{secnumber}}{}{}
\renewcommand\sectionstyle[1]{{%
  \sectionfont
  \textcolor{color1}{\thesecnumber.\quad#1}%
}}

\firstname{First Name}
\familyname{Last Name}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{A Section}
\label{sec.one}
Text goes here 

\section{Another Section}
\label{sec.two}
Text goes here 

\section{Yet Another Section}
\label{sec.three}

Recall in section \ref{sec.one} that we mentioned and in section \ref{sec.two} ... and in section \ref{sec.three} we see

\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]