# Using soul with indirect formatting applied

Tags: macros, highlighting, soul

I am using [the `soul` package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul) to [underline omitting the descenders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/underline-omitting-the-descenders). It seems that passing the following as a parameter works fine

```
 \textit{special text}
```

but if the `\textit` is applied indirectly via the macro `\ApplyStyle` then I get the error:

> Argument of \ApplyStyle has an extra }.

### Question:

Is it possible to allow for this indirect application of the style by changes to the `\varul` macro?  If not, what other options are available (except of course for applying the formatting directly within the invocation of the `\varul` macro -- that would just be too easy :-))?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%%                https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/
%%                    underline-omitting-the-descenders
%%
%%
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \white_text:n #1
      {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {.01}
        \fp_mul:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#1}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{-\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
      }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\whiten}{ m }
        {
          \int_step_function:nnnN {1}{1}{#1} \white_text:n
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{ \varul }{ D<>{5} O{0.2ex} O{0.1ex} +m } {%
\begingroup
\setul{#2}{#3}%
\def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@syllable}%
   \ifdim\dp0>\z@
      \SOUL@ulunderline{\phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
      \whiten{#1}%
      \llap{%
        \the\SOUL@syllable
        \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
      }%
   \else
       \SOUL@ulunderline{%
         \the\SOUL@syllable
         \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
       }%
   \fi}%
    \ul{#4}%
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------

\newcommand{\ApplyStyle}[1]{\textit{#1}}%

\begin{document}
\varul{\textit{special text}\xspace}%      Works!!

\varul{\ApplyStyle{special text}\xspace}%  Does NOT work
\end{document}
```

Comment: On the side, your definition of `\ApplyStyle` could be simplified to `\let\ApplyStyle\textit`...

Comment: @Werner: Yep for the MWE that make sense, but my style selection process is more complicated -- hope that that doesn't introduce any further complications.

Comment: You could add `\ApplyStyle` to the `\SOUL@cmds`: `\SOUL@cmds\expandafter{\the\SOUL@cmds\\1\ApplyStyle}` (or with the interface-macro `\soulregister{\ApplyStyle}{1}`, see comment below). The `1` denotes in both cases a font-changing macro that takes an argument.

Comment: Tell `soul` to leave your command alone with `\soulregister\ApplyStyle{1}`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I first wrote the comment, then I saw yours, then I wrote the answer, then I saw your edit to the comment. Now I hope you weren't preparing an answer yourself...

Comment: Follow-up Question: [Using soul with indirect formatting applied (using macro with 2 parameters, one possibly optional)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125346/using-soul-with-indirect-formatting-applied-usign-macro-with-2-paramaters-one).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`soul` scans the text token by token, a process which can easily be messed up when the input stream also contains macros. The package already knows that it should leave font switching commands alone -- therefore `\textit` works in your case -- but fails with the unknown macro `\ApplyStyle`. Fortunately, there is an interface to make `soul` acquainted with new macros: `\soulregister<command><identifier>`, where `<identifier>` can be either `0` or `1` for the number of arguments (see section 5.2 in the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/pkg/soul); also see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/125354/7674) for an extension of `\soulregister` to accept more, and possibly optional, arguments).

Your example runs fine when adding

```
\soulregister\ApplyStyle{1}
```

to the preamble.