# Using soul with indirect formatting applied (using macro with 2 parameters, one possibly optional)

Tags: macros, highlighting, soul

This is a followup to [Using soul with indirect formatting applied](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125219/using-soul-with-indirect-formatting-applied), where it was determined that using `\soulregister` allows [the `soul` macros](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul) to have font switching macros within the parameters (specifically `\ul` in this case).  However, I am not able to get this to work if the macro has more than one parameter.

#### Single Parameter: `\ApplyStyleA`

This seems to work fine if the macro has one mandatory parameter, as per the answer in [Using soul with indirect formatting applied](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125219/using-soul-with-indirect-formatting-applied).

#### Two Mandatory Parameters: `\ApplyStyleB`

However, if the macro has *two mandatory* parameters, then I get:

> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

#### Two Parameters (one optional): `\ApplyStyleC`

Or, for the case where there is *one optional* parameter and *one mandatory* parameter,  I get:

> TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]

### Notes:

- The MWE as is below compiles fine as the two problematic lines are commented out. So, one needs to uncomment one of those to reproduce the problem.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%%                https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/
%%                    underline-omitting-the-descenders
%%
%%
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \white_text:n #1
      {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {.01}
        \fp_mul:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#1}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{-\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
      }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\whiten}{ m }
        {
          \int_step_function:nnnN {1}{1}{#1} \white_text:n
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{ \varul }{ D<>{5} O{0.2ex} O{0.1ex} +m } {%
\begingroup
\setul{#2}{#3}%
\def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@syllable}%
   \ifdim\dp0>\z@
      \SOUL@ulunderline{\phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
      \whiten{#1}%
      \llap{%
        \the\SOUL@syllable
        \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
      }%
   \else
       \SOUL@ulunderline{%
         \the\SOUL@syllable
         \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
       }%
   \fi}%
    \ul{#4}%
\endgroup
}%
\makeatother
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------


\newcommand{\ApplyStyleA}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleA{1}

\newcommand{\ApplyStyleB}[2]{\textit{#1}}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleB{2}

\newcommand{\ApplyStyleC}[2][]{\textit{#2}}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleC{2}

\begin{document}
This one works just fine:
\varul{\ApplyStyleA{special text}\xspace}%

\medskip
These one leads to ``Extra \}, or forgotten \verb|\endgroup|."
%\varul{\ApplyStyleB{special text}{second paramater}\xspace}%

\medskip
This one leads to ``TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]"
%\varul{\ApplyStyleC[first optional paramater]{special text}\xspace}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `0` and `1` aremore an identifier and not specifically the number of arguments. The digits `7`, `8` and `9` are reserved for superscripts, footnotes and accents respectively. The number is used in `\SOUL@docmd` in a few conditionals. I fear that your commands won’t be recognized by `soul` out of the box. It is also important to know what the optional argument does. Will the content be typeset? How does the command work?

Answer (score 6):

The digit that is used in `\soulregister` does not specify the number of arguments per se.

It is used as an identifier. The digits `7`, `8` and `9` are used for `\textsuperscript` (“and similar”), `\footnote` and accents respectively.

Depending on what the two arguments in `\ApplyStyleB` do (will they both be content that shall be typeset or is one of them used for another purpose) there see various solutions possible.

The same holds true for the `\ApplyStyleC` macro though this is harder to fix as the default value for `#1` is hidden.

Please notice the difference between a simple expansion `\ApplyStyleBa` (type `3`) which will apply the underlining to everything to what `\ApplyStyleBa` expands. The `\ApplyStyleBb` macro uses the proper way as a `1` macro and applies the `soul`ing only to its arguments (type `2`).

Type `4` includes one optional argument. If you want `soul`’s effects also to affect the default optional argument (in your case an empty string, in my case `I'm the default!`), said default text is to be extracted and used in the redefinition of `\SOUL@@`.

Though, if you use the optional argument not to typeset it but to use somewhere else, there is a different approach needed. A few macros (`\minipage` or `\parbox`) uses their first mandatory argument for a dimension, the optional argument as an alignment. To both of these one shouldn’t apply underlining.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xspace}


%% ----------------------------------------------------------------
%%                http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/
%%                    underline-omitting-the-descenders
%%
%%
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
    \cs_new:Npn \white_text:n #1
      {
        \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {.01}
        \fp_mul:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#1}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
        \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{-\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
      }
    \NewDocumentCommand{\whiten}{ m }
        {
          \int_step_function:nnnN {1}{1}{#1} \white_text:n
        }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{ \varul }{ D<>{5} O{0.2ex} O{0.1ex} +m } {%
\begingroup
\setul{#2}{#3}%
\def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@syllable}%
   \ifdim\dp0>\z@
      \SOUL@ulunderline{\phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
      \whiten{#1}%
      \llap{%
        \the\SOUL@syllable
        \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
      }%
   \else
       \SOUL@ulunderline{%
         \the\SOUL@syllable
         \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
       }%
   \fi}%
    \ul{#4}%
\endgroup
}%

\def\SOUL@docmd#1#2{%
    \ifx9#1%
        \def\SOUL@@{\SOUL@addgroup{#2}}%
    \else\ifx8#1%
        \SOUL@doword
        \def\SOUL@@##1{%
            \SOUL@token={\footnotemark}%
            \SOUL@everytoken
            \SOUL@syllable={\footnotemark}%
            \SOUL@everysyllable
            \footnotetext{##1}%
            \SOUL@doword
            \SOUL@scan
        }%
    \else\ifx7#1%
        \SOUL@doword
        \def\SOUL@@##1{%
            \SOUL@token={#2{##1}}%
            \SOUL@everytoken
            \SOUL@syllable={#2{##1}}%
            \SOUL@everysyllable
            \SOUL@doword
            \SOUL@scan
        }%
    \else\ifx1#1%
        \SOUL@doword
        \def\SOUL@@##1{%
            #2{\protect\SOUL@do{##1}}%
            \SOUL@scan
        }%
    \else\ifx2#1%
        \SOUL@doword
        \def\SOUL@@##1##2{%
            #2{\protect\SOUL@do{##1}}{\protect\SOUL@do{##2}}%
            \SOUL@scan
        }%
    \else\ifx3#1%
        \SOUL@doword
        \def\SOUL@@{\expandafter\SOUL@scan#2}%
    \else\ifx4#1
        \SOUL@doword
        \def\@tempa{\renewcommand\SOUL@@[2][}%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@tempa\expandafter\SOUL@get@optional@argument#2]{#2[\protect\SOUL@do{##1}]{\protect\SOUL@do{##2}}}%
    \else
        \SOUL@doword
        #2%
        \let\SOUL@@\SOUL@scan
    \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
    \SOUL@@
}
\def\SOUL@get@optional@argument#1#2#3#4{#4}%
\makeatother
%% ----------------------------------------------------------------


\newcommand{\ApplyStyleA}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleA{1}

\newcommand{\ApplyStyleBa}[2]{\textit{#1} affected? (#2)}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleBa{2}
\newcommand{\ApplyStyleBb}[2]{\textit{#1} affected? (#2)}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleBb{3}

\newcommand{\ApplyStyleC}[2][I'm the default!]{\textit{#2} (I'm not affected again) [#1]}
\soulregister\ApplyStyleC{4}

\begin{document}
\varul{\ApplyStyleA{special text}\xspace}%

\medskip
\varul{\ApplyStyleBa{special text}{second paramater}\xspace}\par %
\varul{\ApplyStyleBb{special text}{second paramater}\xspace}% only expansion

\medskip
\varul{\ApplyStyleC[first optional paramater]{special text}\xspace}\par
\varul{\ApplyStyleC{special text}\xspace}%
\end{document}
```

### Output

> [image]

Comment: I am getting `\end occurred when \ifx on line 125 was incomplete` messages. The 2nd parameter is used to control the formatting options.  I need the entire output of the macro underlined -- Perhaps that is already built into your solution, but since I didn't see this until now (looks like notifications are broken), I may not have enough time to play around with this until tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterGrill I have updated my post. It seems like I somehow missed a `\fi`. Though I'm currently on the phone and can't test it. I'm not a `soul` user, maybe you can include a definition of the macros in your question that covers the real use of them?