# Underline omitting the descenders with Plain TeX

Tags: xetex, plain-tex

I'm reading this question [Underline Omitting the Descenders](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36894/underline-omitting-the-descenders) and wondering if there is a way to do this with Plain TeX and XeTeX.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36947/16967) of Stefan Kottwitz converted to plain TeX. Package `soul` can also be loaded in plain TeX. Package `color` can be loaded with the help of `miniltx`. XeTeX is supported the same way as in LaTeX, package `graphicx` loads the configuration file `graphics.cfg`, which usually detects XeTeX and sets the correct `graphics` driver `xetex.def`.

```
\input soul.sty
\input miniltx
\input color.sty

\def\whiten#1{%
  \llap{\textcolor{white}{{\the\SOUL@token}}\hskip#1pt\relax}%
}
\def\myul{%
  \def\SOUL@everyspace{$\underline{\hbox{\space}}$\kern\z@}%
  \def\SOUL@everytoken{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@token}%
    \ifdim\dp0>\z@
      \raise\dp0\hbox{$\underline{\phantom{\hbox{\the\SOUL@token}}}$}%
      \whiten{1}\whiten{0}%
      \whiten{-1}\whiten{-2}%
      \llap{\the\SOUL@token}%
    \else
      $\underline{\hbox{\the\SOUL@token}}$%
    \fi
  }%
  \SOUL@
}
\resetatcatcode

\font\HugeFont=cmss12 at 20pt
\HugeFont

\myul{jumping quickly}

\bye
```

> [image: Result]