# Problem with \underline{} command!

Tags: fonts, tex-general

I wrote the following commands:

```
The following {\bf {\underline{Approximations}}} and {\bf\underline{Definitions}} is applied in further work
```

The things comes out as:

[image: underline sample]

One is way down than other and looks weird. What is the possible solution so that the distance remains same in all text?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a general remark: They _both_ look weird ... See http://practicaltypography.com/underlining.html

Comment: That's how `\underline` is supposed to work. Don't use underlining in any case whatsoever.

Comment: (i'm sure this has been answered before.)  the descenders in the first word are what's causing the discrepancy.  at the end of the second word, add `\vphantom{p}` to even things out.  but i agree that underlining is to ba avoided unless there's no other possibility (as to leave a space for a signature, for example).

Comment: @Thorsten I am dropping the Idea of underline completely :)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249850/underline-omitting-the-descenders-with-plain-tex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `ulem` addresses this problem. It also works for plain TeX (`\bf`):

```
\input ulem.sty

The following {\bf\uline{Approximations}} and
{\bf\uline{Definitions}} is applied in further work.

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

If you are using LaTeX, then know, that `\bf` is deprecated since decades.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
The following \textbf{\uline{Approximations}} and
\textbf{\uline{Definitions}} is applied in further work.
\end{document}
```

Package `soul` also allows hyphenation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\begin{document}
The following \textbf{\ul{Approximations}} and
\textbf{\ul{Definitions}} is applied in further work.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result soul]

**Typography:** Underlining comes from the time of mechanical typewriters. Font switches were tricky at best. But LaTeX allows for different font shapes, and
bold is more than enough. The usual emphasis command uses italics. Also several ways for emphasis (bold + underline, bold + italics, ...) should not be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
The following \textbf{Approximations} and
\textbf{Definitions} is applied in further work.

The following \emph{Approximations} and
\emph{Definitions} is applied in further work.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result comparison bold italics]