# Underline Hyperlinks Omitting the Descenders

Tags: hyperref, urls

I want to underline links (`\url` and `\vref`, `\href`, ...) omitting descenders in the manner [shown in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67008) while still supporting wrapping of long URIs (via `\UrlBreaks` or otherwise). Ideally, I can also disable it in areas such as ToC or other List Of's.

I've tried a few things but anything I come up with either fails to build or the URL doesn't wrap (as was the case when I redefined `\url` to be `\href{#1}{\varul{#1}}`).

Thanks.