Underline with gaps appropriate for descenders | allow for line breaks
I recently found this answer, which offers very nice underlining, with gaps as appropriate for descenders (e.g. characters like p, q, g, y, etc) [actually, that answer comes from this link].
Unfortunately, this solution does not allow for line breaks. Is there a way to allow for them?

MWE:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}

\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}

\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\myuline{This pygmy gypsy enjoys playing ping pong quickly, but gray puppies happily gather by the pond, yapping loudly as they gallop playfully around. Every year, the playful gypsies organize quirky gatherings for young puppies, hoping they learn to jump joyfully and grasp the playful games they organize.}

\end{document}


This works with line breaks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67008/36296

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks so much for this input. I adopted that solution. I thought it would be a good idea to post it below for reference (just let me know if I should remove it). Thanks a million!

Based on this answer, which was brought up by @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz 's comment,

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{contour}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1.8pt}
\contourlength{0.8pt}
\newcommand{\myuline}[1]{%
  \uline{\phantom{#1}}%
  \llap{\contour{white}{#1}}%
}

\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}
\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \white_text:n #1
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_tmpa_fp {#1 * .01}
    \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
    \llap{\textcolor{white}{\the\SOUL@syllable}\hspace{-\fp_to_decimal:N \l_tmpa_fp em}}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand{\whiten}{ m }
    {
      \int_step_function:nnnN {1}{1}{#1} \white_text:n
    }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{ \varul }{ D<>{5} O{0.2ex} O{0.1ex} +m } {%
\begingroup
\setul{#2}{#3}%
\def\SOUL@uleverysyllable{%
   \setbox0=\hbox{\the\SOUL@syllable}%
   \ifdim\dp0>\z@
      \SOUL@ulunderline{\phantom{\the\SOUL@syllable}}%
      \whiten{#1}%
      \llap{%
        \the\SOUL@syllable
        \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
      }%
   \else
       \SOUL@ulunderline{%
         \the\SOUL@syllable
         \SOUL@setkern\SOUL@charkern
       }%
   \fi}%
    \ul{#4}%
\endgroup
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

No line breaking:\\
\myuline{This pygmy gypsy enjoys playing ping pong quickly, but gray puppies happily gather by the pond, yapping loudly as they gallop playfully around. Every year, the playful gypsies organize quirky gatherings for young puppies, hoping they learn to jump joyfully and grasp the playful games they organize.}\\

With line breaking:\\
\varul{This pygmy gypsy enjoys playing ping pong quickly, but gray puppies happily gather by the pond, yapping loudly as they gallop playfully around. Every year, the playful gypsies organize quirky gatherings for young puppies, hoping they learn to jump joyfully and grasp the playful games they organize.}

\end{document}


