# \Colorhref not getting affected by \Large

Tags: hyperref, links

I'm trying to render the following prhase:

```
{\Huge \Colorhref{http://google.com}{Google} - This is a link}
```

the "This is a link" part renders with the **huge** modifier, however my **Google** link looks tiny.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I tracked down `\Colorhref{}` to a post here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/link-formatting-colors-underlines-in-moderncv --- and there `\small` command is used inside the definition

Comment: Is there a any package, that defines `\Colorhref` already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A small working example, where I removed the `\small` statement from the definition. The original command stems from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14309/31729

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\Colorhref[3][cyan]{\href{#2}{\color{#1}#3}}

\begin{document}

{\Huge \Colorhref{http://google.com}{Google} - This is a link}


\end{document}
```

[image]