# How can I disable the border around the email address in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, links

I am trying to remove the red border around the email address, I tried to use the following code, but the border is still there. How can I remove it?

```
\usepackage[hidelinks=true]{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
    pdfborder = {0 0 0}
}
```

Comment: Try to put `\hypersetup` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: have a look at the following answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44377/36296

Comment: None of them solves the problem.

Comment: Class `moderncv` (2013/04/29 v1.5.1) already uses `pdfborder = 0 0 0`. The link could be added by the PDF viewer using a heuristics to detect links from text. Try a different PDF viewer. Also a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be a good idea.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek the PDF reader was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class `moderncv` (2013/04/29 v1.5.1) already uses `pdfborder = 0 0 0`:

```
\AtEndPreamble{
  ...
  \hypersetup{
     ...
     pdfborder = 0 0 0,
     ...
  }
}
```

If the values for `pdfborder` or some of the other settings should
be changed, then it can be done via `\AtEndPreamble` to get after the settings of class `moderncv`:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \hypersetup{hidelinks}% or pdfborder = 0 0 0, ...
}
```

But this is not needed here, because the setting for `pdfborder` is already correct.

The link can also be added by the PDF viewer using a heuristics to detect links from text. Then it is helpful to try a different PDF viewer.