# How to convert LaTeX 2.09 to LaTeX2e

Tags: document-classes, obsolete

I'm trying to convert a LaTeX 2.09 template to LaTeX2e (pdflatex):

http://www.yisongyue.com/resume/

How should I convert this line ?

```
\documentstyle[hyperref, margin, line]{res_yy}
```

I don't know what class I need to use

```
\documentclass{article} %% ???
\usepackage{res_yy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{line}
```

Comment: [Looks like](http://www.yisongyue.com/resume/res_yy.sty) a rather specialist style file! I very much doubt you'll be able to do a 'quick' conversion (_i.e._ without reworking a lot of the code). There is no `res_yy` class for LaTeX2e.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Comment: By the way, did you try just compiling the document 'as is' with LaTeX2e. There is some auto-detect code to try to work in 'compatibility mode'.

Comment: Sure, compiling the document 'as is' work. I've been using this template for 6 years now. But I would like to use LaTeX2e feature like \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} and so on.

Comment: Well I found a res_yy.sty. It loads article.sty. So you could try to remove the line `\input article.sty` in a (renamed) copy of res_yy.sty and then load it with `\usepackage` and look what happens. If you want to use hyperref you should also remove the `\nofiles` command.

Answer (score 12):

The short answer is that there is no *easy* conversion for a completely general case. LaTeX2.09 style files are very much a mix of formatting and 'additional' code, even more than is the case with LaTeX2e.

More specifically, the LaTeX2.09 style in question has never been converted into a LaTeX2e class. That means that there the change

```
\documentstyle{res_yy}
```

to

```
\documentclass{res_yy}
```

is not possible: the later does not exist. That leaves you needing to recreate the layout and macros provided by `res_yy` in LaTeX2e. This is certainly possible, but I suspect that the effort is not really balanced off by the outcome. The amount of work needed to do the conversion seems at least equal to starting either from `article` or a [specialist CV class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae).

Answer (score 2):

I was using the exact same style file for N years and having a hard time today to use some packages. Here's the hack I succeeded based on Ulrike's suggestion.

First, replace following lines in res_yy.sty

```
\input article.sty

\ds@centered
\ds@overlapped
```

with

```
%\input article.sty
\ds@line
\ds@margin
```

Then, in the main .tex file, replace

```
\documentstyle[hyperref, margin, line]{res_yy}
```

with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{res_yy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

After this, your `.tex` will compile with 'line' and 'margin' style.

I can finally use the `enumitem` package with this style. Yes!