# Build custom \itemize

Tags: formatting, lists, itemize

I'd like to create a CV similar to the one shown [here](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/images/design-cv-resume/evalotta_lamm.pdf). But I don't know what's the best way to create those text blocks. I had the idea to use itemize. But I don't know how to format the label of the \item in italics. I also get in trouble when trying to spread a label on multiple lines (eg. when the content of the label is too long for one line).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
June 2007  Responsible for the visual design and HTML / CSS
–present   templating for a social media site where people
           discuss their unusual pets.

Another    Some text
Date
```

The label should be in italics.
I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: you can try [`moderncv`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/moderncv)

Comment: Or a simple table will do?

Comment: @cmhughes Done. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of ways to create a cv- perhaps another answer will demonstrate an approach using `moderncv`

If you want to use `itemize`, then you can customize it (and every other list-type environment, such as `enumerate`, `description`, etc) using the extremely powerful and user-friendly `enumitem` package.

A very simple implementation gives

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[font=\itshape]
    \item[June 2007|Oct 2008] \lipsum[1]
    \item[Nov 2008|present] \lipsum[2]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

You could also use (for example)

```
\begin{itemize}[font=\itshape,align=parleft,labelwidth=2cm]
    \item[June 2007|\\present] \lipsum[1]
```

which gives

[image]

For more reading, you might like to look at

[LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Comment: Works fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a quick example of using `moderncv`. You can find some themes and a template file for usage in your TeX distro folder for `moderncv`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\PassOptionsToPackage{pdfpagelabels=false}{hyperref} 
\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}
\firstname{Felis}
\familyname{Caracal}
\address{Serengeti}{Serengeti - South Africa}
\mobile{+1-555-MIAOUW}
\phone{+1-555-PURRRR}
\email{caracal@felix.nl}
\homepage{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caracal}
\photo[64pt]{Caracal001}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Summary}
Goal oriented. Experienced in strategic planning and element of surprise. Huge jumps in career. Expert in predator-prey dynamics.

\section{Professional Experience}
\subsection{Field Experience}
\cventry{2003--2005}{Team Leader}{Caracals! Logistics}{Serengeti}{\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serengeti}{Wiki Page}}{%
A selected collection of the completed projects:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Lead my team to hit various targets.
\item Avoided many threats.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{2005--present}{Freelancer}{}{}{}{%
Carried out individual population control experiments
}
\section{Languages}
\cvlanguage{Gibberish}{Native}{}
\section{Interests}
\cvline{High Jump}{Professional}
\cvline{Cooking}{Beginner}
\end{document}
```

[image]