# LaTeX template for a professional looking CV

Tags: templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

I know there are couple of similar questions. However most of their answers are links to LaTeX libraries.

Can I ask kindly for an example that illustrates using LaTeX for writing a professional CV?

Comment: Kieran Healy has a nice [github](http://kjhealy.github.com/kjh-vita/) of his CV. And our own @JosephWright has a nice series of [blog posts](http://www.texdev.net/2011/11/05/writing-a-curriculum-vitae-in-latex-part-1/) on writing a CV.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I removed the thanks. This is just the style here. Thanks is best expressed through voting for answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for the info, but the kjh-vita.tex is not compilabale!. I get many errors.

Comment: In blog [LaTeX Matters](http://texblog.org) you can find an article called [Writing a CV in LaTeX](http://texblog.org/2012/04/25/writing-a-cv-in-latex/) where is explained how to use it and also some links to CV templates.

Comment: "Many errors" is an unhelpful way of describing what has gone wrong. Are you compiling with XeLaTeX as mentioned on the page?

Comment: Your question is far too vague considering how specific you expect the answer to be.  Different fields/disciplines will have different expectations regarding what must be in the CV, and where it should go.  If the suggested links are no good, then you need to explain more clearly what 'professional CV' means to you.