# Model of curriculum vitae with Latex

Tags: templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

Please, is there any patterns (model or package) to download to do a cv with latex?

Thank you so much

Comment: A quick search would show you that this question has already been answered -- several times.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This looks like a duplicate of [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae). Could you clarify how it differs?

Answer (score 0):

I found that this site has plenty of good templates. Just remember that he usually uses a set of professinal fonts. Compiling the document will require that you install those fonts on your system.

http://www.latextemplates.com/cat/curricula-vitae