# No indent in res.cls

Tags: indentation, resume

I am writing a resume using [`res.cls`](http://ctan.org/pkg/res). 
I would like to write a non-indented paragraph under a section heading but can't figure out how to override the heavily indented margins used for columns under sections. I have tried `\flushleft` and a few other things but that nothing has worked. Anyone have any suggestions?

A minimal working example illustrating the undesired indentation:

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you be able to include a small example of a resume to work with, rather than having to generate something from scratch? We call this an [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/5764).

Comment: `\noindent` won't work?

Comment: Unless you've committed a lot of time to using this class (which is very old, and poorly documented) you might want to consider some of the more modern CV/resume classes.  See this question for some possibilities: [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/2693).

Comment: I added a MWE example with its image to your question; I hope it's OK.

Answer (score 4):

As **Alan Munn** suggests in his comment, you should consider using another document class (`res.cls` is very old, and poorly documented). That being said, according to the comments on `res.cls`, you can solve your problem using the `\newsectionwidth{<length>}` command which controls the amount that the section titles go in the left margin; a little example:

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\newsectionwidth{0cm}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One One}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The above solution moves the section title to the right; now that I reread the question, perhaps the desired effect is to leave the title as it is and move the block of text to the left; if this is the case, `\parshape` will do the job:

```
\documentclass{res}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[4]

\section{Test Section Two}
\parshape 1 -\sectionwidth \resumewidth
\lipsum[4]

\section{Test Section Three}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \parshape 1 -\sectionwidth \resumewidth worked great. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Joslyn you're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer (this is different from up-voting it), In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).