# Which document class for writing resume?

Tags: document-classes, resume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae)

I am trying to create a new resume in LaTeX previously I used Scribus but not happy with the formatting and pdf size.

To begin with I am very new to LaTeX and don't know much about formatting, I find it really hard to decide on the document class and how to indent the text accordingly.

I want a manual indent with heading on the left and accompanying content on the right or middle. But with default document class `article` everything seems to be centered indented.

Here is the screenshot of my previous resume which I am considering as a base guide for the new one.

[image: Resume created in Scribus]

[image: Latex Styling]

Can you please help me getting acquainted with alignment. It will be great if you can point me to some good materials.

Comment: I would think that [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/5764) contains some valuable resources; perhaps making this a duplicate.

Comment: I personally use a simple `documentclass` like `article` and then use `geometry` to help with page settings. For the content in your screenshot, I'd use a `description` or `itemize`

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/arc/training/latex/resumes/) is the website I used when using LaTeX to write my resume.

I don't have access to my .tex file right now, but I'm pretty sure it's its own document class (resume is the class, I think? I'll check and update this when I can). But the nice part about using the files from this site is that you don't have to worry about align at all (unless you want to do something different than what the template is doing); it'll line things up in a logical and appealing way automatically.

EDIT: Since checking my .tex file, my documentclass is in fact `{res}`. so I am using the class that the website I linked to provides.