# Give me my fancy math  from mathptmx back!

Tags: math-fonts, newtxmath, calligraphy, mathptmx

In the old times of `mathptmx`, we wrote stuff such as

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
Let \(\mathcal{X}=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\).
\end{document}
```

and got from `pdflatex` a fancy calligraphic math , which was sufficiently fancy to be visibly distinct from the remaining italicized math  in ₁ till ₙ:

[image: nice distinctive]

However, in the more modern times, `mathptmx` has been obsoleted in favor of `newtx`.
Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
Let \(\mathcal{X}=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\).
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` results in a dull

[image: dull calligraphic X]

The distinction between the first X and the remaining occurrences is far less prominent. This is unfortunate, as it requires additional attention from the reader to distinguish between the two.

For `pdflatex`, what is the advised way of getting the fancy math , such as in `mathptmx`, [image: FreeSerif symbol], or similar, if you use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` for standard text and math fonts? Yes, I know that one can use an image (with the traditional caveats of, e.g., X not appearing in the PDF text layer), and, I know there is `mathrsfs`, which is not obsolete in CTAN but is pretty dated (1999-06-30 is the date of the file `mathrsfs.sty` on the CTAN file system and 1996-01-01 is the internal date stated inside `mathrsfs.sty`). Is it still advisable to use `mathrsfs`+`\mathscr` or are there better options?

Crosspost: http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=112487 .

Comment: Technically, it was the `txfonts` package, *not* the `mathptmx` package, that was obsoleted by the `newtxtext`/`newtxmath` pair of font packages.

Comment: That last font could be my scribble for "9C".

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE6Gx.png looks like "9C".

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the desired *X* by loading the `mathrsfs` ("Ralph Smith's Formal Script") font package and writing `\mathscr{X}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
Let \(\mathscr{X}=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\).
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Just_A_Man - On what basis do you judge the `mathrsfs` package to be "dated". (Being several years old is not the same as being dated...)

Comment: @Just_A_Man You are humble and generous... that is my wish.

Comment: @Just_A_Man In the meantime I would like to thank you and inform you that I am one of the most modest users of LaTeX ans also in the English language. I try with all my heart to help you as much as I can and I send you my regards.

Answer (score 29):

The author of `newtxmath` also wrote (and actively maintains) the package [`mathalpha`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha), to easily declare calligraphic, script, fraktur, and blackboard bold math alphabets. With `mathalpha`, you can get your script *X* with the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[cal=rsfs]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
Let \(\mathcal{X}=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

By using `scr` instead of `cal`, the *X* will be obtained from the command `\mathscr` instead of the command `\mathcal`.

Comment: This is the most elegant way to do it: a comprehensive, consistent interface with features like bold alphabets and scaling.

Comment: @Davislor yes, that's also what I think! The documentation of the package is also very useful, with complete examples from all of the available fonts.

Answer (score 7):

mathptmx uses this font here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{ztmcm}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
Let \(\mathcal{X}=\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}\).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does anything prevent you to simply try it out? But if you are happy with a \mathscr command, why did you reject Sebastiono's quite sensible answer?

Comment: I would suggest that you open the style and check its content. And then ask Sebastiano to undelete his answer so that you can accept it.

Comment: @Just_A_Man - I don't believe that your claim that "old styles (as well as old software in general) tend to die and get useless" is valid, at least not when it comes to LaTeX font packages. But if you insist, you can switch from `\usepackage{mathrsfs}` to `\usepackage[scr=rsfs]{mathalfa}`, as the `mathalfa` package should satisfy your "must not be dated" requirement.

Comment: @Mico: LaTeX suffers less from this than most software ecosystems, thanks to an extremely strong culture of long-term backward-compatibility.  But it still does suffer from it — older packages get deprecated and experts recommend newer alternatives, for various reasons.  Search e.g. `deprecated package` and `obsolete package` on this site for many examples, and see [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95180/how-to-tell-people-why-packages-become-deprecated-and-shouldnt-be-used-anymore) for some good overall discussion.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine - I must have expressed myself very unclearly. It was *not* my intent to claim that no LaTeX packages ever became obsolete or deprecated. (Indeed, under the OP's query, I noted that the `newtx` font package had been obsoleted by the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` font packages.) The point I tried to make was merely that the time passed since the last time a LaTeX package has been updated needn't be a valid indicator for it being obsoleted.