# Moving contact information above horizontal line in resume

Tags: resume

I'm working on a resume, and was playing around with a template I found online. Here is what I had:

```
\documentclass[margin,line,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{First Last \vspace*{.1in}}
\begin{resume}

\section{\sc Contact Information}

\vspace{.05in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.75in}p{2.1in}}
Address 1 & Phone \\
Address 2 & E-mail\\
\end{tabular}
\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

But I would prefer to have the contact information above the horizontal line and not have it as a "section" in the resume. I tried removing line, from the document class line and adding in a horizontal line manually, but it's messy and probably not perfect:

```
\documentclass[margin,pifont,palatino,courier]{res}

\begin{document}
\name{First Last}
\begin{resume}

\vspace{-.1in}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{2.7in}p{2.1in}}
555 Name Street North & (555) 555-5555 \\
City ST 55555 & myemail@email.com\\
\end{tabular}

\vspace{-0.35cm}
\hspace{-3.3cm}\noindent\rule{16.5cm}{0.4pt}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Is there a cleaner and "right" way of doing this? Thanks.

Edit: I changed the code to a minimal working sample. Sorry if what I had posted before was too long.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Please try supply a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) instead of a full example. This will help understanding your problem (I'm trying to emphasize minimal here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line between the contact info and name is specified inside `\fullline` (and used in case the `line` class option is specified).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% makes a line of width \textwidth starting at -\hoffset
%
\def\fullline{      % hrules only listen to \hoffset
  \nointerlineskip  % so I have this code     
  \moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\textwidth} 
  \nointerlineskip
}
```

You can remove the line by redefining this to suit your needs using the `xpatch` package or `etoolbox`: just put this in your preamble (between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`):

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\fullline{\hrule width\textwidth}{}{}{}
```

However IMHO there are better ways to create a custom [CV in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae).