# Right Alignment of text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, tabbing

i am a newbie on LaTeX. After writing a simple code

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}
\begin{document}

 \begin{tabbing}
  Sample1  \` sample2 \\ 
\end{tabbing}

\begin{resume}
\end{resume}


\end{document}
```

I got an output with a black underline.

```
                                    Sample1                                              sample2
```

but the `Sample1` lies just at the center of the page, not at the left side. What I  want is to display `Sample1` in the left side, and `Sample2` on the right side. I need a code for that with tabbing. How is this possible ?

Comment: The `res` document class is quite old. For better methods for writing one's resume using LaTeX, you may want to check out the posting [LaTeX template for resume/curriculum vitae](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/5001).

Comment: Is there really a need for `tabbing` here? You're not actually using any tab stops though...

Answer (score 3):

Okay, my advice is not to do this, but if you need to arm-wrestle `res` into doing what you describe you could:

```
\documentclass[margin,line]{res}

\begin{document}

\hspace{-33mm}sample1 \hfill sample2

\begin{resume}
\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

However, it would be a much better idea to find a resume that looks like you want, and adapt that code, rather than forcing this.

The length of -33mm is something I got by tinkering.  If it doesn't look quite right to you, you can adjust it.

Comment: The OP uses the `res` rather than the `article` document class. With the `res` document class in use, your code doesn't succeed in pushing "Sample 1" all the way to the left hand side of the text block.

Comment: Ah... I didn't notice that.  I think it's the `margin` option for `res` that pushes it right.

Comment: @kmacinnis: You are shy about `0.4pt` in your "tinkering". :) You should rather use `\hspace{-1.3in}`, as the `margin` class option sets a section width of `1.3in`.

Comment: Always glad to be improved upon!