# LaTeX Resume Templates Modifications

Tags: errors, templates, cv

I was using the LaTeX [resume template](http://www.constantinos.us/code/resume.tex) from http://www.constantinos.us/blog/2006/04/12/latex-resume-template site.. Then i have modified accordingly given below .. But unfortunately it is showing some error and i cant find out the solution for such a long time

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[left=1.90cm, right=1.80cm, top=2.00cm, bottom=1.50cm]{geometry}
\newcounter{magicrownumbers}
\newcommand\rownumber{\stepcounter{magicrownumbers}\arabic{magicrownumbers}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\textheight=10in
\pagestyle{plain} % Page Number
%\raggedbottom
\raggedright

%\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{cg}
%\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{lgrcmr}

% DEFINITIONS FOR RESUME
\newcommand{\area}[2]{\vspace*{-9pt} \begin{verse}\textbf{#1}   #2 \end{verse}  }
\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\}
\newcommand{\header}[1]{{\hspace*{-15pt}\vspace*{6pt} \large{\textsc{#1}}} \vspace*    {-6pt} \lineunder}
\newcommand{\employer}[2]{{ \underline{\textbf{\emph{#1}}} (#2) \\}}
\newcommand{\PublicationListing}[1]{{ \underline{\textbf{\emph{#1}:-}} \\}}
\newcommand{\contact}[3]{\vspace*{-8pt}

%\begin{center} {\LARGE \scshape {#1}}\\ #2 \lineunder #3 \end{center} \vspace*{-8pt}}
\begin{center} {\Large \scshape {#1}}\\ #2 \lineunder #3 \end{center} \vspace*{-8pt}}

\newenvironment{achievements}{\begin{list}{$\bullet$}{\topsep 0pt \itemsep -2pt}}    {\vspace*{4pt}\end{list}}
\newcommand{\schoolwithcourses}[3]{ \textbf{#1} #2 #3}
\newcommand{\school}[3]{ \textbf{#1} #2 #3}
\newcommand{\UniversityInformations}[7]{ {\textbf{#1}} #2 {$\bullet$ \underline{#3}} {\underline{#4}} #5 {\underline{#6}} {\textit{#7}}}
% END RESUME DEFINITIONS

\begin{document}

\small
%\smallskip
\vspace*{-44pt}
\contact{My Name}{Research Engineer \\ \textit{Work Address}:- Room No\#1019     (10\textsuperscript{th} Floor),SAC; Dept. of EECS, \href{http://www.abc.edu/}{abc University},city \# 1229, country \\ 
\textit{Home Address}:- xyz, (3\textsuperscript{rd} Floor), House \# 123, Road \#456, CDF , Merul Badda, Dhaka}
{\Mobilefone +880-172837, \phone +880-364759 \Letter \it{myname@eecs.abc.edu}     \Letter \it{abcname@gmail.com} \\ 
\textit{Website}:-\ComputerMouse \it{\href{https://sites.google.com/site/xyz/}{https://sites.google.com/site/xyz/}}}

\header{Education}
%\UniversityInformations{\href{http://www.abc.edu/html/dcse.html#bseee}{Bachelor of Science in Electrical \& Electronic Engineering}; Summer-2012;} {\href{http://www.abc.edu/}{abc University}; Country \\} {GPA:- 3.79/4.00} {$\bullet$ Major GPA}{:- 3.84/4.00}{$\bullet$ Honors:-}{Magna Cum Laude}

\school {\href{http://www.abc.edu/html/dcse.html#bseee}{Bachelor of Science in Electrical \& Electronic Engineering}; Summer-2012;} {\href{http://www.northsouth.edu/}{abc University}; Country \\} {$\bullet$ \underline{GPA}:- 3.79/4.00 $\bullet$ \underline{Major GPA}:- 3.84/4.00 $\bullet$ \underline{Honors}:-\textit{Magna Cum Laude}} \\ 

{\underline{\textbf{Undergraduate Thesis}}:- {\it xyz ahdma hdahf hadjfh dafhadj fhdahf jkdah }}\\
\textbf{Supervisor:-} \href{http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~xyz/}{Dr. fhdjahf jadhfjhad }   
\textbf{Co-Supervisor:-} \href{http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~mky/}{Dr. fjjahsfjdha kjfhadjk hfad}

\header{Research Interests}
$\diamond$ ashfahsd fhadjfh djakhfj kdajkfjha  $\diamond$ dhjkdsha fbdahf kdabfjdah $\diamond$ dhjhaksjhfadfdagfad $\diamond$ dgysga fhdagfjdahgkfhdajkhf ad $\diamond$ dhashgfkjahdfkjhaddkhfajkjdh $\diamond$ dfagsdkfhadkfbad \& $\diamond$ dbfjadsjfkhdakjfjkdahfjkkdahj fdkjfh fdkjhfjda jfhdajk fhdah .

\header{Awards \& Achivements}
$\bullet$ Achieved 50\% Tuition waiver (Financial Assistantship) at     \href{http://www.abc.edu/html/moreadmission.html#financial}{abc University}, Country. \\

$\bullet$ One of my papers was short listed at \href{http://www.opticsinfobase.org}{\it {Best Student Paper Competition LEDs, Photovoltaics, \& Optoelectronics in Energy}} of \href{http://www.acp-conf.org/}{Asia Communications and Photonics Conference (ACP) 2012}, China.

\header{Work History}
Department of Electrical Engineering \& Computer Science (EECS.), {\bf     \href{http://www.abc.edu/html/moreadmission.html#financial}{ABC University}}, Country. \\

\employer{Research Assistant:-}{From June-2012 to Present}
\begin{achievements}
\item \underline{Project Title}:- {\it ehdjfhajdhfjdahfjhds jfdhsj sjkdhf kjjdsh jdshjg hsdjhg skjhgvu hsgjkhsf jkghsj fhvkjhfs gkhsj ghs } \\
Project Supervisor: \href{http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~xyz/}{Dr. ABC}

\item \underline{Project Title}:- {\it Transmission of Nearfield fjhdajfh djkahfjdah kjfhdj fhdjh gjkdhg jkhsdgh sdjkhg sfjghs jdk} \\
Project Supervisor: \href{http://www.eecs.qmul.ac.uk/group/fjehdjfhadjhfa.htlm}{Dr. xyz abc}
\end{achievements}
```

errors are given in following links

1. [error --> it is saying](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7em2x6x0up7gbgq/Untitled.png) 
       Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa ...derline{Honors}:-\textit{Magna Cum Laude}}
2. Problem : I cant
   add space after  the header line .. How to add little more space
   after it
3. How to make it justified ? It always becoming left alligned .. How to make it justified ?
4. How to increase the font size a little bit ?

Thanks in advance for your support :)

Comment: Is it possible to make a simpler coding (for template definition) with similar output ?

Comment: Is there any suggestion .. How to make a modern  CV in easy way ..?

Comment: For 3: remove `\raggedright`. For 4: Add `11pt` or `12pt` to the documentclass options (e.g. `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`. There are links to a bunch of different templates in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80/latex-template-for-resume-curriculum-vitae

Answer (score 1):

The original template as well as the code you are giving us is
a bit of a mess ;-)

- The first error you encounter is thrown because you try to bold
  face a hyperlink. If you want the stuff bold, do
  `\href{http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends}{\bfseries A
  nice place to hang out}`.
- I redefined the `\lineunder` macro to use predefined LaTeX
  lengths, they can be changed to suit personal taste.
- If you want the resume to be justified, remove `\raggedright`
  which makes a ragged right margin.
- If you want the font to be bigger, my first duggestion would be
  to remove `\small` which makes the current font smaller. If you
  feel to need an even bigger font size, do as
  [Torbjørn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t)
  says in the comments and use either `11pt` or `12pt`.

The whole thing was cluttered with changes of horizontal space,
which was obviously due to a positive parskip as well as spurious
spaces. I set the `parindent` to zero, which can be done in this
case without any regrets.

I left the rest of the resume template untouched and recommend
everybody *not* to use it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newcommand{\lineunder}{\vspace*{-8pt} \\ \hspace*{-18pt} \hrulefill \\}
\renewcommand{\lineunder}{\par\hrulefill\bigbreak}
\newcommand{\header}[1]{{\large{\textsc{#1}}\par}\lineunder}
\newcommand{\school}[3]{\textbf{#1} #2 #3\par}
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\underline}{}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
%\small
\header{Research Interests}
\school{\href{http://www.northsouth.edu/}{\textbf{I am searching Zelda}}; Summer-2012;}
{\href{http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends}{A
nice place to hang out}; Country }
{$\bullet$ \underline{GPA}:- 3.79/4.00 $\bullet$ \underline{Major GPA}:- 3.84/4.00 $\bullet$ \underline{Honors}:-\textit{Magna Cum Laude}}
\end{document}
```

[image: ibrahimResume]