# Reducing spacing between section headings and text in resume

Tags: spacing, cv, resume

I want to reduce vertical spacing between end of text in education section and the title of the following section , i.e. ACADEMIC APPOINTMENT. Also, the space between PUBLICATION and  Economics Journal. Finally want to know how to make the same space between section heading and text for each of sections in the resume.

My minimal working code is below;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{res}  
\usepackage{datetime}   
\usepackage{parskip}                                 
\newdateformat{mydate}{\monthname[\THEMONTH] \THEYEAR}   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   



\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\rhead{\footnotesize Name, PhD \thepage} 
\headsep = 0.5cm

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\headsep = 0.0cm
}
\fancyfoot[L]{\footnotesize updated\today}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\setlength\headheight{10pt}
\setlength\headsep{8pt}
\addtolength\topmargin{-18pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{empty}}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

\topmargin=-0.5in  

\oddsidemargin=0.0in 
\evensidemargin=0.0in 
\textwidth=6.0in 

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} 

\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.3in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.6in} 
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 


\name{\LARGE Name, PhD\\[12pt]} 
\begin{resume} 
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.20in}p{3.75in}p{3.00in}}
 & Department of XXX              &  (XXX) XXX XXXX  \\            
 & XXXX   & Email:\href{mailto: nameu@XX.org}{name@xx.org} \\      
 &  Street number and name &  Fax: (XXX) XXX XXXX\\       
 &City, Zip XXXXX  &  \\       
\end{tabular}

\section{\line(1,0){475}} %creates a horizontal line below the header

\section{\textnormal{EDUCATION}}
\vspace{0.1in}
{Ph.D.} Economics, XXX University \hfill 2009 \\
{M.S.} Statistics, ZZZ University \hfill 2010 \\

\section{\textnormal{ACADEMIC APPOINTMENTS}}
\vspace{0.1in}
{Assistant Professor,XXX} \hfill 2012-present\\\
{Research Scientist,YYY}\hfill 2010-2012\\
\section{\textnormal{RESEARCH INTERESTS}}
\vspace{0.1in}
Primary:XX and YY  \\
Secondary: ZZ
\section{\textnormal{PUBLICATIONS}}
\subsection{\textnormal{Economics Journal}}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\renewcommand\refname{} 
\bibitem{XX2014a}  XX. and XX. "The first publication",\emph{ Name of the journal}, vol.X, pp.XX-YY, YYYY

\end{thebibliography}


\section{\textnormal{TEACHING EXPERIENCE}}

Course \hfill Semester Year \\
Course \hfill Semester Year \\
\end{resume} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my point of view, you should not use this 'old' class. It's from 2000 (as far as I know see in a quick check)

Answer (score 1):

The vertical space before a section is set in `res.cls` by `\sectionskip`, which you can redefine by placing something like this in your preamble:
`\sectionskip=1.5ex plus 0.7ex minus -.2ex`
On the other hand, `\subsection` is never mentioned in the file, but there is a line that says `\LoadClassWithOptions{article}` so it must use the default `\subsection` from the `article` class. Spacing before and after section titles is usually adjusted using the `titlesec` package, but trying to incorporate that into your MWE generates a lot of errors.

As @ChristianHupfer mentioned in his comment, using a modern package would be much better. There are many packages available for typesetting a CV or résumé.

Comment: Thank you very much you all for your suggestions. yes, I also realized that using titlesec generates lots of errors and found out that it does not go well with res class as well. I am assuming that  I can easily find example of a modern package for CV.

Comment: You've probably found this already, but I'll share a relevant link anyway. http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/80/24974